# NIntegrate is resetting my variables and not giving me a result?

Tags: formatting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to check if mass conservation holds by integrating the area under a curve but to no avail.

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]; 
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]

Clear[Eq0, EvapThickFilm, h, Bo, ϵ, K1, δ, Bi, m, r]
Eq0[h_, {Bo_, ϵ_, K1_, δ_, Bi_, m_, r_}] :=
  D[h, t] + Div[(-h^3)*Bo*Grad[h] + h^3*Grad[Laplacian[h]] + ((δ*h^3)/(Bi*h + K1)^3)*Grad[h]
  + m*(h/(K1 + Bi*h))^2*Grad[h]] + ϵ/(Bi*h + K1) + r*D[D[h^2/(K1 + Bi*h), x]*h^3, x] == 0;

L = 2*92.389; 
TMax = 2491.29*100; 
Off[NDSolve::mxsst]; 
hSol[x_, y_, t_] = h[x, y, t] /. 
   NDSolve[{EvapThickFilm[0.003, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.025, 0], 
      h[0, y, t] == h[L, y, t], h[x, 0, t] == h[x, L, t], 
      h[x, y, 0] == 1 + (-0.25*Cos[2*Pi*(x/L)] - 0.25*Sin[2*Pi*(x/L)])*
         Cos[2*Pi*(y/L)]}, h, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, {t, 0, TMax}, 
     MaxStepFraction -> 1/60][[1]]
```

When I use `NIntegrate[...]` to integrate under the area of the curve for a single value of `TMax`, I don't get a single valued number. In fact, my variables are reset! What gives?

```
NIntegrate[hSol[x, y, 0.1*TMax], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}]
```

I've tried it with simpler 2D cases instead of 3D and this works fine.

FOOTNOTE: Is there some way I could *host* this code elsewhere? Any websites that support mathematica code format?

## EDIT 1:

The error that `NIntegrate[..]` gives me is that x = L is not a valid limit of integration. whilst L has actually been defined in the problem previously.

Comment: Please don't post your entire assignment/project and ask us to debug. It's not easy to do, especially when we don't know the background to your problem. It might be better if you can reduce the issue to a small, readable code snippet and people can think over it and give you a solution over a coffee break :)

Comment: @R.M Yes, I realize that. I don't know where else I could post the code itself so as to focus on the problem that the code is stricken by **here**! :(

Comment: Also, code in box form, e.g. with `SubscriptBox`, etc, is extremely difficult to read. Can you convert it to `InputForm` and repost? To do so, select the cell, right click (ctrl-click on mac), and Convert To -> InputForm.

Comment: @rcollyer did that. Still is an ugly mass of text. Boy mathematica sure can be an ugly environment. Anyway...

Comment: Actually, that's readable now.

Comment: You can host your code on [GitHub gists](https://gist.github.com/), for example. However, I would agree with @R.M. that *usually* the necessity to do that would indicate insufficient work done on your part to localize the problem (I can imagine that there are exceptions, of course)

Comment: The are a few problems with this code. First, most variables should be declared numeric (using, e.g.,  Bo_?NumericQ instead of Bo_). Second, the passing of the function h[x,y,z] is problematic and ugly. EvapThickFilm uses it, but it isn't in its variable list.It also uses the variables x,y,z which are local to the NDSolve. Very, very ugly.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Oh...you are saying x,y,z are local to NDSolve? It does make sense.. But this has actually worked on [this](https://gist.github.com/2229043)? I am not a mathematician at all neither am I into programming so I don't have your keen eye to say that this is ugly! :)

Comment: What I mean is that the definition of `EvapThickFilm` contains `h[x, y, t]` which can be manipulated outside of `EvapThickFilm` as it isn't local to `EvapThickFilm`. This is potentially dangerous. By the way, the line `EvapThickFilm(Bo, \[Epsilon], K1, \[Delta], Bi, m, r); ` in your code should be removed.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Hmm thats all food for thought. I'll carefully read my code and try to understand your constructive comments in that perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the symbols you're using depend on the `VectorAnalysis` package.  So, be sure to execute the following *from a fresh kernel*.

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
```

Also, be sure to define your `hSol` function for only numeric values.

```
hSol[x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ,t_?NumericQ] := ...
```

Comment: This is the answer. However, I couldn't ever have known of the `_?NumericQ` thingy! I'll have to look it up. Aah, the trials and tribulations of being a paper and pencil engineer!