# What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?

Tags: programming, core-language, faq, guidelines

As you may already know, *Mathematica* is a wonderful piece of software.
However, it has a few characteristics that tend to confuse new (and sometimes not-so-new) users. That can be clearly seen from the the fact that the same questions keep being posted at this site over and over again.

Please help me to identify and explain those pitfalls, so that fewer new users make the mistake of walking into these unexpected traps.

Suggestions for posting answers:

- One topic per answer
- Focus on non-advanced uses (it's intended to be useful for beginners/newbies/novices and as a question closing reference)
- Include a self explanatory title in h2 style
- Explain the symptoms of problems, the mechanism behind the scenes and all possible causes and solutions you can think of. Be sure to include a beginner's level explanation (and a more advanced one too, if you're in the mood)
- Include a link to your answer by editing the **Index** below (for quick reference)

### Stability and usability

- #### Learn how to use the Documentation Center effectively
- #### Undo is not available before version 10
- #### Don't leave the Suggestions Bar enabled
- #### The default $HistoryLength causes Mathematica to crash!

### Syntax and semantics

- #### Association value access `[]` vs `[[]]`
- #### Basic syntax issues
- #### What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs
  mean?
- #### Understand that semicolon (;) is not a
  delimiter
- #### Omitting ; can cause unexpected results in functions
- #### Understand the difference between `Set` (or
  `=`) and `Equal` (or
  `==`)
- #### The displayed form may substantially differ from the internal
  form
- #### Mathematica's own programming model: functions and expressions

### Assignment and definition

- #### Lingering Definitions: when calculations go
  bad
- #### Understand the difference between `Set` (or
  `=`) and `SetDelayed` (or
  `:=`)
- #### Understand what `Set` (=) really
  does
- #### Attempting to make an assignment to the argument of a
  function
- #### Assuming commands will have side effects which they
  don't:
- #### How to use both initialized and uninitialized variables

### General guidelines

- #### Avoiding procedural
  loops
- #### Understand the difference between exact and approximate (Real)
  numbers
- #### Using the result of functions that return replacement
  rules
- #### Use Consistent Naming
  Conventions
- #### User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and
  NumericQ
- #### Mathematica can be much more than a scratchpad
- #### Understanding `$Context`, `$ContextPath` the parsing stage and runtime scoping constructs
- #### How to work always in WYSIWYG mode?

### Graphics and images

- #### Why do I get an empty plot?
- #### Why is my picture
  upside-down?
- #### Plot functions do not print output (Where are my plots?)
- #### Use `Rasterize[..., "Image"]` to avoid double rasterization

### Tricky functions

- #### Using `Sort` incorrectly
- #### Misunderstanding `Dynamic`
- #### Fourier transforms do not return the expected result
- [Association/<||> objects are Atomic and thus unmatchable before 10.4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119542/6804)
- [Association has HoldAll(Complete)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119675/6804)

Comment: Few suggestions: 1. old definitions in memory and "overloaded" functions like `f[x_]:=a; f[x_Integer]=b`; 2. Forgotten underscore in patterns `f[x]=a` 3. `Set` vs `SetDelayed`; 4. `m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} // MatrixForm` and then `Eigenvalues[q]`; 5. Plotting complex function produces empty plot without any warnings.

Comment: I want to throw `$HistoryLength` in there, a memory management in general category including `MaxMemoryUsed` and `MemoryConstrained` etc

Comment: Suggestion: Don't mess with `Dynamic` before you can master `Plot`. Be real and patient. You are learning a new language, it doesn't matter if you are a C master

Comment: Suggestion: If appropriate to the problem, force Mathematica to use approximate numerical algorithms to avoid the computational overhead of their symbolic counterparts. There are several ways to do this (e.g., NIntegrate vs. Integrate, using real approximate numbers instead of integers in equations, etc).

Comment: Suggestion: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18483/193 (Using the result of functions that return replacement rules)

Comment: By a long mile, my biggest problem as a beginner was the tendency of the Front End to work for a long time and then crash. I cannot tell you how much time this wasted, because then I usually had to quit the application from Activity Monitor. After I installed a modified version of a previously circulated quit-on-any-message handler, the problem mostly went away. That is why I strongly believe stop on message should be a default-on feature of the Mathematica Front End.

Comment: Maybe there should be a (short) answer about security. Most people don't realize mathematica has a large set of functions that are capable of taking over your computer entirely, or as a more specific example, activating your webcam (`CurrentImage`).

Comment: @belisarius, Can I suggest to have a similar guide like "Effective use of notebooks for beginners?"

Comment: @caya Of course. I find it very interesting. You can post it as a (CW) question.

Comment: @carlosayam, I looked through your profile, but couldn't find it.  Did you ever ask the notebook question?

Comment: Fantastic. Someone should also add an answer for how to retrieve elements from multi-dimension arrays. Another suggestion would be to Optimize of graphics and plots for print or save to readable format. Will help students do their assignments on Mathematica.

Comment: While adding, do you remove answers as well? I've went through the batch and find it interesting overall. There are some however, some newer association posts for example, that aren't helpful to a new user. In my opinion he or she should be drawn in with understanding of the practical common basics.

Comment: This is actually a kind of silly question, but how can one format their question like @Mr.Wizard did?

Comment: @SumNeuron You can click [**edit**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/18393/edit) to see the markdown code used in the post itself.  For general instruction see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: "As you may already know, Mathematica is a wonderful piece of software.", oh yes: we know. Yet, this product has the ability to enchant you over and over, and... over, endlessly. It goes beyond wonderful. I am proud to be (a tiny) part of this community.

Comment: I find it very surprising that Sum defaults to GenerateConditions->False.   e.g. 

In[3]:= Sum[a^i,{i,1,\[Infinity]}]
Out[3]= -(a/(-1+a))

In[2]:= Sum[a^i,{i,1,\[Infinity]},GenerateConditions->True]
Out[2]= -(a/(-1+a)) if Abs[a]<1

I think this issue should be documented here. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125592/surprising-behavior-of-sum?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 322):

## What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?

Questions frequently arise about the meaning of the basic operators, and I hope it will prove useful to have a sort of index for them. It would be nice to have them organized by sign instead of topic, but they do not have a natural order.  One can use the find/search feature of a browser to locate an operator in the list.

Below are links to documentation explanations for most of those shorthand signs together with a short example.  Read the documentation for an explanation and more examples.  See also the guide to [Wolfram Language Syntax](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html), which has links to most of these.  In a couple of cases, I give different links that seem more helpful to me.

All those operators come with a specific precedence. Assuming an incorrect precedence of your operators can wreak havoc with your programs. For instance, the `&` operator, which is part of a pure function specification, has a rather unexpectedly low precedence, and constructions using it quite often need to be protected with parentheses in order to make things work as intended (for instance, as option values). So, please have a look at this gigantic [precedence table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html).

Most (but not all) of these can be looked up using the `?`-syntax, for example evaluating `? /@` will show help for `Map`.  They can also be found by searching for them in the Documentation Center (Help menu). In older versions of Mathematica certain operators must be quoted before searching for them, e.g. search for `"?"` to find `PatternTest`.

Version information may be found at the bottom of the documentation pages of each command.  Consult the online page if you do not have the latest version of *Mathematica* to see when a function was introduced.

Beginners may have difficulty in identifying shorthand signs correctly. For example, is `_?` a whole shorthand sign or the combination of `_` and `?`? In this case, `Hold` and `FullForm` can be revealing:

```
Cases[Range[500], _?PrimeQ] // Hold // FullForm
(* Hold[Cases[Range[500], PatternTest[Blank[], PrimeQ]]] *)
```

By further searching `PatternTest` and `Blank` in document, we'll know `_?` is actually combination of `Blank[]` (`_`) and `PatternTest` (`?`).

**Function application**

- `@`, `[...]`, `//` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseShorthandNotations.html) -- `f @ x` = `f[x]` = `x // f` (`Prefix`, circumfix and `Postfix` operators for function application)
- `~` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html) -- `x ~f~ y` = `f[x, y]` (`Infix`; see `Join` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) for a **Basic Example**.)
- `/@` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) -- `f /@ list` = `Map[f, list]`      (not to be confused with `f @ list`, when `f` is [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html))
- `@@` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) -- `f @@ list` = `Apply[f, list]`
- `@@@` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html) -- `f @@@ list` = `Apply[f, list, {1}]`
- `//@` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAll.html) -- `f //@ expr` = `MapAll[f, expr]`
- `@*` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) -- `f @* g @* h` = `Composition[f, g, h]`
- `/*` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html) -- `f /* g /* h` = `RightComposition[f, g, h]`

Infix `~` should not be confused with:

- `~~` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) -- `s1 ~~ s2 ~~ ...` = `StringExpression[s1, s2, ...]`
- `<>` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html) -- `s1 <> s2 <> ...` = `StringJoin[s1, s2, ...]`

**Pure function notation**

- `#`, `#1`, `#2`, ... [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) -- `#` = `#1` = `Slot[1]`, `#2` = `Slot[2]`, ...
- `##`, `##2`, ... [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) -- `##` = `##1` = `SlotSequence[1]`, `##2` = `SlotSequence[2]`, ...
- `#0` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) gives the head of the function, i.e., the pure function itself.
- `&` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) -- `# &` = `Function[Slot[1]]`, `#1 + #2 &` = `Function[#1 + #2]`, etc.
- `|->` or `\[Function]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) -- `x \[Function] x^2` ([image]) = `Function[x, x^2]`

**Bracketing**

- `[`, `]` -- `f[x, y, ...]`; function application and [the underlying form of all expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html#4715)
- `{`, `}` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) -- `{x, y, ...}` = `List[x, y, ...]`
- `[[`, `]]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) -- `expr[[n]]` = `Part[expr, n]`; also `expr[[n1, n2,...]]` = `Part[expr, n1, n2,...]`.
- `(`, `)` -- parentheses, used for grouping only (not function application)
- `<|`, `|>` [[ref]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) -- `<| a -> b, c -> d, ... |>` = `Association[a -> b, c -> d, ...]`
- `(*`, `*)` -- `(*some text*)`; an inline comment
- `\[`, `]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html) -- `\[charactername]`; special characters, e.g. `\[CapitalOmega]` for `Ω`
- `\(`, `\)` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowBox.html) -- `RowBox`, a low-level head used in constructing notebook expressions (rare)

**Assignments**

- `=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) -- `=` = `Set`     (not to be confused with `==` -- `Equal`!)
- `:=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) -- `:=` = `SetDelayed`
- `=.` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unset.html) -- `=.` = `Unset`
- `^=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSet.html) -- `^=` = `UpSet`
- `^:=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html) -- `^:=` = `UpSetDelayed`
- `/:  =` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html) -- `/:  =` = `TagSet`
- `/:  :=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) -- `/:  :=` = `TagSetDelayed`
- `/:  =.` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagUnset.html) -- `/:  =.` = `TagUnset`

**Special assignments**

- `//=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html) -- `x //= f` = `ApplyTo[x, f]`; equivalent to `x = f[x]`
- `+=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AddTo.html) -- `x += n` = `AddTo[x, n]`; equivalent to `x = x + n`
- `-=`[[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubtractFrom.html) -- `x -= n` = `SubtractFrom[x, n]`; equivalent to `x = x - n`
- `*=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimesBy.html) -- `x *= n` = `TimesBy[x, n]`; equivalent to `x = x * n`
- `/=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DivideBy.html) -- `x /= n` = `DivideBy[x, n]`; equivalent to `x = x / n`
- `++`

  - [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Increment.html) `x++` = `Increment[x]`; sets `x = x + 1`, then evaluates to the old value of `x`
  - [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PreIncrement.html) `++x` = `PreIncrement[x]`; sets `x = x + 1`, then evaluates to the new value of `x`
- `--`

  - [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Decrement.html) `x--` = `Decrement[x]`; sets `x = x - 1`, then evaluates to the old value of `x`
  - [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PreDecrement.html) `--x` = `PreDecrement[x]`; sets `x = x - 1`, then evaluates to the new value of `x`

**Relations**

- `==` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) -- `==` = `Equal`      (not to be confused with `=` -- `Set`, or with `Equivalent`!)
- `===` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) -- `===` = `SameQ`
- `!=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unequal.html) -- `!=` = `Unequal`
- `=!=` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnsameQ.html) -- `=!=` = `UnsameQ`
- `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` -- [`Less`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Less.html), [`Greater`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Greater.html), [`LessEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LessEqual.html), [`GreaterEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GreaterEqual.html)
- `∈`, `\[Element]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html) -- `Element`

**[Rules and patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RulesAndPatterns.html)**

- `->` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) -- `->` = `Rule`     (also can specify `DirectedEdge`)
- `<->` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TwoWayRule.html) -- `<->` = `TwoWayRule`     (also can specify `UndirectedEdge`)
- `:>` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) -- `:>` = `RuleDelayed`
- `/;` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) -- `patt /; test` = `Condition[patt, test]`
- `?` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) -- `p ? test` = `PatternTest[p, test]`      (not to be confused with `Information`)
- `_`, `_h` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) -- Single underscore: `_` = `Blank[]`, `_h` = `Blank[h]`
- `__`, `__h` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html) -- Double underscore: `__` = `BlankSequence[]`, `__h` = `BlankSequence[h]`
- `___`, `___h` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html)  -- Triple underscore: `___` = `BlankNullSequence[]`, `___h` = `BlankNullSequence[h]`
- `..` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) -- `p..` = `Repeated[p]`
- `...` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedNull.html) -- `p...` = `RepeatedNull[p]`
- `:` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) or [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) -- `x : p` = pattern `p` named `x`; or, as a function argument, `p : v` = pattern `p` to be replaced by `v` if `p` is omitted.
- `_.` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html), [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html) -- Represents an optional argument to a function, with a default value specified by `Default`.
- `|` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) -- `|` = `Alternatives`     (not to be confused with `||` -- `Or`!)
- `/.` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) -- `expr /. rules` = `ReplaceAll[expr, rules]`
- `//.` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) -- `expr //. rules` = `ReplaceRepeated[expr, rules]`

**[Logical operators](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LogicAndBooleanAlgebra.html)**

- `&&`, `∧` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html) -- `&&` = `And`     (not to be confused with `&` -- `Function`!)
- `||`, `∨` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html) -- `||` = `Or`
- `!`, `¬` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Not.html) -- `!` = `Not`
- `\[Implies]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Implies.html) -- `\[Implies]` = `Implies` ([image])
- `\[Equivalent]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equivalent.html) -- `\[Equivalent]` = `Equivalent` ([image])
- `⊼` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nand.html) -- `⊼` = `Nand`
- `⊽` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nor.html) -- `⊽` = `Nor`
- `⊻` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Xor.html) -- `⊻` = `Xor`
- [image] [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Xnor.html) -- [image] = `Xnor`

**List**

- `;;` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) -- `expr[[i ;; j]]` = `Part[expr, Span[i, j]]`; also `expr[[i ;; j ;; k]]` = `Part[expr, Span[i, j, k]]`.
- `.` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) -- `a.b`, `a.m.b`; the dot product of vectors or matrices (`List`s)

**Numeric**

- `+`, `-`, `*`, `^` -- [`Plus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html), [`Subtract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subtract.html) (or [`Minus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minus.html) as a prefix), [`Times`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html), [`Power`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html)
- `*^` is equivalent to `*10^` (e.g. `3*^2=300`).
- `^^` gives a way to enter a number in a different base (e.g. `2^^100101` represents the binary number $100101_2 = 37$). See more info in the documentation of [BaseForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseForm.html).
- `` ` ``, ``` `` ``` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html)/[[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html), [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html) -- Indicates `Precision`, and `Accuracy`, respectively, when following a number. There is a table of typical examples in the tutorial [Numerical Precision](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html#30813).  When `` ` `` follows a symbol, it denotes a context. More information about contexts can be found in some of the tutorials in [this overview](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThingsOverview.html).

**[Graph construction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphConstructionAndRepresentation.html)**

- `\[DirectedEdge]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedEdge.html) -- `\[DirectedEdge]` = `DirectedEdge` ([image] or `->`/`Rule` may be used)
- `\[UndirectedEdge]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UndirectedEdge.html) -- `\[UndirectedEdge]` = `UndirectedEdge` ([image] or `<->`/ `TwoWayRule` may be used)

**Probability**

- `\[Distributed]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distributed.html) -- `\[Distributed]` = `Distributed` ([image])
- `\[Conditioned]` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conditioned.html) -- `\[Conditioned]` = `Conditioned` ([image])

**Evaluation history and control**

- `%` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html) gives the last result generated. `%%` gives the result before last. `%n` (= `Out[n]`) gives the result on the *n*th output line. Not to be confused with `Percent` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Units/ref/Percent.html).
- `;` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) -- `a;b;c` = `CompoundExpression[a,b,c]`. `;` is an expression separator, used to evaluate some number of expressions in sequence, for example in the body of `Module[]`. When evaluated with no trailing `;`, the value returned is the value of the last expression. Note that `x;` returns `Null`.

**Files and Packages**

- `<<` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html) -- `<<` = `Get`
- `>>` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put.html) -- `>>` = `Put`
- `>>>` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PutAppend.html) -- `>>>` = `PutAppend`

**Symbol information**

- `::` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageName.html) -- `f::usage` = `MessageName[f, "usage"]`. (Note that since v13.1 `::` is also experimentally used for `TypeSpecifier` when the first argument is a string.)
- `?`, `??` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html) -- `? f` = `Information[f, LongForm -> False]`, `?? f` = `Information[Sin]`.  See also [`Definition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Definition.html) and its undocumented relatives discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/copying-one-symbol-into-another). Not to be confused with `?` when following a pattern (`PatternTest`).

**Other**

- `$` is not an operator; it can be used in variable names (e.g. `my$variable`). It is commonly used for `` System` ``  constants and parameters (e.g. `$Version`) and for local variables generated by scoping constructs (e.g. `Module[{x}, x]` $\rightarrow$ `x$9302`).
- `a ** b ** c` [[*ref*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) = `NonCommutativeMultiply[a, b, c]` (not given a built-in value)
- Similar to `**` there are numerous operator forms which can be used with their special symbols in unary or infix form and which carry no predefined meaning. A list can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147329).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you... I don't think I can say it enough times.

Comment: Nice compilation.

Comment: It is probably nice to know that for quick reference, just entering the notation in the documentation search bar will give you the right page in most cases.

Comment: and here I always thought that UpSet is `:-(` ... sorry

Comment: Btw, this is called [grawlixes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86838/what-the-is-that-called).

Comment: Just as a comment on a syntax issue that caused me problems when I had less experience, === and =!= allow to compare expressions of different types, like a number and a list, whereas == and != would return unevaluated in 2 == {} . Using TrueQ in this case garantees to get a boolean TrueQ[2 == {}]

Comment: `StringMatchQ` also treats certain characters as special, see the details and options section of the [documentation of StringMatchQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html).

Comment: One question - I'm still confused about `# &` = `Function[Slot[1]]`, which I don't understand how to interpret. I know expressions like `Function[x,dosomethingwith[x]]` which is the same as `dosomethingwith[#] &`, is there more to it?

Comment: So equal things are not always interchangeable? I mean, if `#` = `Slot[1]` and `# &` = `Function[Slot[1]]` then I would guess that the latter is also the same as `Function[#]`

Comment: You can apply `FullForm` to those expressions and see that it is so.

Comment: Hm I see. I just somehow don't understand what to make of `Function[#]`. Can such expression occur in any context at all?

Comment: I think I understand now. Using your example, `#^2 &` and `Function[x,x^2]` are also equivalent to `Function[#^2]`, right?

Comment: Should `?`, `??`, `::` and `;;` be added to this?

Comment: Also `\``'s meaning in terms of contexts might be good to mention.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Is `Esc` + `fn` + `Esc` useful to mention?

Answer (score 145):

### Basic syntax issues

1. **Mathematica is case-sensitive**. `sin` is not the same as `Sin`.
2. **Symbol names cannot contain underscore. `_` is a [reserved character](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html) used for pattern matching.** To make this type of symbol naming possible use *Mathematica* letter-like form `\[LetterSpace]`, or shorter <kbd>Esc</kbd>_<kbd>Esc</kbd>, which looks like usual underscore with smaller opacity.
3. ***Avoid using subscripted symbols in your code.*** While [it can be done](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1004), it causes a lot of confusion and is harder to use than just `sym[j]` or whatever your symbol might be. [The reason is that subscripted symbols are not plain symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/871), so you can’t assign values (strictly speaking, `DownValues`) to them directly. See also [general discussion about "indexed variables"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/14303).
4. ***Avoid single-capital-letter names for your variables***, to avoid clashes (consider using the double-struck <kbd>Esc</kbd>dsA<kbd>Esc</kbd> and Gothic letters <kbd>Esc</kbd>goA<kbd>Esc</kbd> instead). *Mathematica* is case-sensitive. More generally, avoid capitalising your own functions if you can. (See [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117877) for a listing of the reserved capital letters.)
5. *Mathematica* uses square brackets `[]` for function arguments, unlike most other languages that use round parentheses. See [halirutan's exemplary answer for more detail](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17412/8).
6. Learn the difference between [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`) and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`). See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8829/8) and [this tutorial in the *Mathematica* documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html).
7. **Use a double `==` for equations.** See [this tutorial in the *Mathematica* documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html#5158) for the difference between assignments ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html), `=`)  and equations ([`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html), `==`).
8. When creating matrices and arrays, don't use formatting commands like `//TableForm` and `//MatrixForm` in the initial assignment statements. This just won't work if you then want to manipulate your matrix like a normal list. Instead, try defining the matrix, suppressing the output of the definition by putting a semicolon at the end of the line. Then have a command that just reads `nameOfMatrix//MatrixForm` -- you can even put it on the same line after the semicolon.
   The reason for this is that if you define the object with a `//MatrixForm` at the end, it has the form `MatrixForm[List[...]]`, instead of just `List[..]`, and so it can't be manipulated like a list. If you really want to display the output as `MatrixForm` on the same line you can do `(nameOfMatrix=Table[i+j,{i,5},{j,5}])//MatrixForm`
9. [Functions are defined](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) with e.g. `func[x_, y_] := x + y` — not `func[x, y] := x + y`, *not* `func(x_, y_)`, and *not* `func(x, y)`.
   The expression `x_` is interpreted as `Pattern[x, Blank[]]`.  (See [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html) and [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html).) Parentheses are used only for grouping and not to surround arguments of functions.
10. **Syntax help.** WolframAlpha is [integrated with *Mathematica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframAlphaIntegration.html) and can be used to get help with coding simple computations.  Begin your input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>=</kbd> followed by some text to convert the text to code; or use or <kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to get full WolframAlpha output.
    For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> followed by `solve sinx=0`, or `plot gamma(z)`, or `integrate e^(2x)`.

Comment: I've been using subscripted symbols for simple linear equations, like point slope, i.e (y_1 - y_0)=m(...); Solve[%,y_1]. It works ok; but there is definitely conflicts if I combine a symbol and subscripted version of that same symbol, i.e.( y - y_0)-m(...); Solve[%,y] causes conflicts for me.

I guess this problem can become even more severe in more complex operations? Pitty, cause when I use pad and paper, I love mixing 'y' and 'y_0' /etc..

Comment: On point 6, I often use `(mat = matrixExpression)//MatrixForm` which first evaluates `matrixExpression` and assigns it to `mat` and only then displays the result (i.e. `mat`) in MatrixForm

Comment: Damn! A lot of these keep coming  and coming as questions.Oh  Eternal September!

Comment: After too many semesters of my physics students calling `NDSolve` incorrectly, I started an expanded answer for point #7 (`Set` vs. `Equal`) just now.

Answer (score 141):

### Avoiding procedural loops

People coming from other languages often translate directly from what they are used to into *Mathematica*. And that usually means lots of nested `For` loops and things like that. So "say no to loops" and get programming the *Mathematica* way! See also [this excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45958/8) for some guidance on how Mathematica differs from more conventional languages like Java in its approach to operating on lists and other collections.

1. Use [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Attributes.html) to check if functions are [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html). You can avoid a lot of loops and code complexity by dealing with lists directly, e.g. by adding the lists together directly to get element-by-element addition.
2. Get to know functions like [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html), [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html), [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhileList.html), [`Inner`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inner.html) and [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html). You can use many of these to produce the same results as those complicated nested loops you used to write.
3. Get to know [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) (`/@`), [`Scan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Scan.html), [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) (`@@` and `@@@`), [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html), [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html) and [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html). You'll be able to operate on complex data structures without loops using these.
4. Avoid unpacking/extracting parts of your data (via `Part` or `Extract`) and try to handle it as a whole, passing your huge matrix directly to `Map` or whatever iterative function you use.
5. See also these Q&As: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/4330), [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

> **keywords:** loop for-loop do-loop while-loop nestlist foldlist procedural

Comment: Rather than post a separate answer perhaps something about packed arrays could be added to this answer. This is a handy link: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/391/

Comment: What are the performance advantages of avoiding procedural loops? I suppose some people may resort to them for readability.

Comment: @BlackMilk late answer, I know, but triply nested For loops are NOT more readable than the alternatives.

Comment: dont follow this advice or you wont be able to read your code. Procedural programming is the most used paradigm at the moment (over 90% of all languages)

Comment: @timoftebogdan. I disagree- this is a site about Mathematica, so it is not relevant if nested loop-itis is popular in other languages. And Map is a lot more readable than For...etc

Comment: @Verbeia does it not all depend on perspective and use case? I like programming with compile/C in mind and there are many situations in which I find a loop on the top level natural. Support for that perspective can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2159/4330).

Comment: With present Mathematica technology, one is forced to use loops if the data set being operated on does not fit in physical memory.  In these cases the values must be generated and used at each step of possibly nested loops.

Comment: Like Matlab. You should understand the ways of vectorizing the code in matlab. That's something I've never been used to. I'm searching for a book or an excellent comprehensive tutorial just about vectorizing the code in matlab

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom In the link that you provided it is said that using nested for loops is ok when you have vectorized inner loops by some other means. I agree with that. Anyway we should always have performance in mind and you know using nested loops in mathematica tends to low preformance.

Answer (score 131):

### Understand that semicolon (;) is not a delimiter

Although it may look to newcomers that semicolons are used in *Mathematica* as statement terminators as in C or Java, or perhaps as statement separators as in Pascal and its derivatives, in fact, semicolons are the infix form of the function `CompoundExpression`, just as plus-signs (+) are the infix form of the function `Plus`.

You can verify this by evaluating

```
Hold[a; b; c] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Hold[CompoundExpression[a, b, c]]
> ```

`CompoundExpression` is necessary to *Mathematica* because many of the core programming functions such as `SetDelayed` (:=), `Module`, `Block`, and `With` take only a single expression as their second argument. This second argument is of course the code body and normally requires the evaluation of many expressions. `CompoundExpression` provides the construct that bundles an indefinite number of expressions into one.

Wolfram Research chose semicolon for the infix operator form of `CompoundExpression` to make *Mathematica* code look more like C code, but this is only syntactic sugar.

The only true delimiter in *Mathematica* is comma (,).

#### Update

One often sees code like the following

```
data = RandomReal[{0., 10.}, {1000, 2}];
```

The variable `data` is probably going to be used as test or example data. The semicolon is added to suppress the output from this `Set` expression because the output is both very large and no one really cares about its details. Because there is no visible output, it would be easy to assume the expression returns nothing, but that is not true. *Mathematica* expressions always return *something*, even if it is only the token `Null`, which does not print in `OutputForm`. In the case of `CompoundExpression`, there is an additional twist -- I quote from the *Mathematica* documentation:

> *expr1; expr2;* returns value `Null`. If it is given as input, the resulting output will not be printed. `Out[n]` will nevertheless be assigned to be the value of *expr2*.

This the only case I know of where evaluating an expression at toplevel doesn't assign its actual output to `Out[n]`.

**keywords** delimiter terminator separator semicolon compound-expression

Comment: perhaps a bit more on the actual effect of `;`?

Comment: @YvesKlett. I think posts to this CW are meant to be restricted to pitfalls and not meant to be replacements for general documentation.

Comment: But a common pitfall is not to suppress output or improper use of `,` vs. `;` in `Module` etc.

Comment: @YvesKlett. Yes, that's true. Why don't you write that up as another pitfall? Or edit this contribution to include your point? (After all, it's a CW)

Comment: Aww shucks, the curse of commenting on CW (CoCoCW) ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't *binary form* be *infix form*? In fact, `CompoundExpression` is in general *not* a [binary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)!

Comment: It should be noted that `;` has a lower [precedence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html#17226802) than almost everything, including both `Set` and `SetDelayed`. So, to use them in conjunction with each other, parentheses or a scoping construct needs to be used.

Comment: Perhaps as part of this answer it may be added the typical "times by Null" mistake. For example `Module[{result}, For[...`, in the loop `result` is assigned, and then, without a semicolon after closing `For`, on the next line, `result`.

Comment: I disagree with m_goldberg about avoiding "replacements for general documentation." Each of the many gaps in Mathematica's documentation leads directly to a pitfall. In that situation, a gap filled is a pitfall avoided.

Comment: well then what symbol is used as expression terminators in Mathematica? It seemed to me that we add `;` at the end of the expression to prevent its result being printed just as MATLAB?

Comment: "Wolfram Research chose semicolon for the binary operator form of CompoundExpression to make Mathematica code look more like C code"

Also at least OCaml and Scala use semicolon is to compound expressions, just like in Mathematica.

Comment: @Rojolalalalalalalalalalalalala Love your new Palito-Ortega-inspired name

Comment: I care about the details!

Comment: @Tdonut. if so, all you have to do is omit the semi-colon. A terminating semi-colon is entirely optional.

Comment: I agree with Yves that the most common pitfall regarding the semicolon, at least for me, is omitting it in modules like here: `Module[{a, b},
  a = 1
     b = 2
     Print[{a, b}]
  ];` The same code would work fine if not wrapped in a Module. Shall we include this here or in a separate answer?

Answer (score 125):

### Using the result of functions that return replacement rules

Most new *Mathematica* users will at some point encounter the seemingly odd formatting of the output given by functions such as [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve&lang=en) or [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Root.html).

Let's start with the follwing simple example:

```
Solve[x^2 == 4, x]
```

> {{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}}

You might find this output strange for two reasons. We'll have a look at both.

#### What do the arrows mean?

The output that [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve&lang=en) returns, is what is called a replacement rule in *Mathematica*. A replacement [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html?q=Rule&lang=en) is of the form `lhs -> rhs` and does not do much on its own. It is used together with other functions that apply the rule to some expression. The arguably most common of these functions is [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll&lang=en), which can be written in the short form `/.`. As the documentation states

> *expr/.rules*
>
> applies a rule or list of rules in an attempt to transform each subpart of an expression expr.

In practice, this looks like the following:

```
x + 3 /. x -> 2
```

> 5

Notice how `/.` and `->` are combined to replace the `x` in the expression `x+3` by `2`. And this is also how you can use the [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve&lang=en) output. The simplest form would be:

```
x /. Solve[x^2 == 4, x]
```

> {-2,2}

Since you will often face more complicated problems and [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve&lang=en) and its ilk might take quite some time to evaluate, it makes sense in theses cases to only calculate the solutions once and save them for later use. Just like many other expressions, replacement rules can be assigned to symbols using [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html?q=Set&lang=en):

```
sol = Solve[x^2 == 4, x];
x /. sol
```

> {-2, 2}

#### Why the nested structure?

At first glance, the nested structure of the output looks strange and you might ask: why is the output of the form `{{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}}` when it could just be `{x -> -2, x -> 2}`?

To understand this, take a look at the following:

```
x /. {x -> -2, x -> 2}
```

> -2

Replacement rules can be given in lists to make things like `x + y /. {x -> 1, y -> 2}` work. When only a single list of rules is given (as in the example above), only one replacement is made for each variable. As the result shows, *Mathematica* replaces `x` with the first matching rule it finds. In order to have *Mathematica* make two (or more) replacements and output a list, the rules have to be given as lists of lists.

The nested structure also makes more sense as soon as you start using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve&lang=en) and other functions with more than one variable.

```
Solve[{x + y == 6, x^2 == y}, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> -3, y -> 9}, {x -> 2, y -> 4}}

You can still apply this list of rules to expressions with either `x` or `y` or both. If you only want a certain solution you can access the element you want either before or after replacement, using functions like [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/First.html?q=First&lang=en), [`Last`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Last.html?q=Last&lang=en) or [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html?q=Part&lang=en) (which is usually written in its postfix form `[[...]]`):

```
sol2d = Solve[{x + y == 6, x^2 == y}, {x, y}];
First[x - y /. sol2d]
x - y /. First[sol2d]
Last[x - y /. sol2d]
x - y /. sol2d[[2]]
```

> -12
>
> -12
>
> -2
>
> -2

#### Values

In addition to `expr /. rules`, one can use `Values` or the various newer alternative-output versions of solvers that end with `Value` or `Values`, which have been introduced over a period from version 10 to version 12.3.

Example: Here are three ways to get the solution values to a system of equations:

```
sol = Solve[{x + y == 6, x^2 == y}, {x, y}];
{x, y} /. sol
```

> ```
> (*  {{-3, 9}, {2, 4}}  *)
> ```

```
SolveValues[{x + y == 6, x^2 == y}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> (*  {{-3, 9}, {2, 4}}  *)
> ```

```
Values@Solve[{x + y == 6, x^2 == y}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> (*  {{-3, 9}, {2, 4}}  *)
> ```

The alternative-output solvers are `AsymptoticDSolveValue, AsymptoticRSolveValue, DSolveValue,  NDSolveValue, NSolveValues, ParametricNDSolveValue, RSolveValue,  SolveValues`. The easy way to find them is to enter the desired solver and immediately follow with a capital `V`; command-completion will show you the alternative and whether it ends with an `s`.

#### Further reading

For more discussion of using rules, see

- The tutorial [Applying Transformation Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html).
- Blachman, [Demystifying Rules](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v8i4/features/blachman/contents/DemystifyingRules.pdf), *The Mathematica Journal* **8**:4 (2002).

Comment: This seems more like a guide than a "pitfalls" post.  I encourage you to consider posting this under one of the questions that specifically deals with this issue instead, e.g. [(3175)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3175/121), [(6669)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121), [(9035)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9035/121).

Comment: The OP asked for things that tend to confuse new users and this certainly confused me. But I totally see your point. (except for the fact that the post about the documentation above e.g. seems more like a guide, too) maybe we can tweak my answer to make it better meet the purpose of this wiki.

Comment: I see *your* point after a second read, so +1.  Tweaking is fine with me.  I commented above partly because you aren't going to get "reputation" for answers in this community-wiki thread as you would if this answer were elsewhere, if that matters to you.

Comment: Note that as of V10, one can use [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) to extract the values from the lists of rules.

Comment: The section about the nested structure answered an old question of mine. +1

Answer (score 105):

### Understand the difference between `Set` (or `=`) and `SetDelayed` (or `:=`)

A common misconception is that `=` is always used to define *variables* (such as `x = 1`) and `:=` is used to define *functions* (such as `f[x_] := x^2`). However, there really is no explicit distinction in *Mathematica* as to what constitutes a "variable" and what constitutes a "function" — they're both *symbols*, which have different *rules* associated with them.

Without going into heavy details, be aware of the following important differences (follow the links for more details):

- `f = x` will evaluate `x` first (the same way as `x` would be evaluated if given as the sole input), then assigns the result of that evaluation to `f`.  `f := x` assigns `x` to `f` without evaluating it first.  A simple example:

  ```
   In[1]:= 
   x = 1;
   f1 = x;
   f2 := x;

   In[4]:= Definition[f1]
   Out[4]= f1 = 1

   In[5]:= Definition[f2]
   Out[5]= f2 := x
  ```
- `=` is an *immediate* assignment, whereas `:=` is a *delayed* assignment. In other words, `f = x` will assign the value of `x` to `f` at *definition time*, whereas `f := x` will return the value of `x` at evaluation time, that is every time `f` is encountered, `x` will be recalculated. See also: [1](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html), [2](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node97.html), [3](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node98.html)
- If you're plotting a function, whose definition depends on the output of another possibly expensive computation (such as `Integrate`, `DSolve`, `Sum`, etc. and their numerical equivalents) use `=` or use an `Evaluate` with `:=`. Failure to do so will redo the computation for *every plot point*! ***This is the #1 reason for "slow plotting".*** See also: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1305/5), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320355)

At a slightly more advanced level, you should be aware that:

- `=` holds only its first argument, whereas `:=` holds *all* its arguments. This does not mean however that `Set` or `SetDelayed` don't evaluate their first argument. In fact, they do, [in a special way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408310/unwanted-evaluation-in-assignments-in-mathematica-why-it-happens-and-how-to-de/7409957#7409957). See also: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320731)
- `=` still pattern-matches if pattern names were present in the rhs at definition time. For example, if `x` is definitionless, `f[x_] = x` will be the identity function no matter what values `x` takes on later. This is because at the end of the day, Mathematica still learns a replacement rule due to `=`, as can be seen with `` Language`ExtendedDefinition ``.
- `=`, in combination with `:=`, can be used for [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), which can greatly speed up certain kinds of computations. See also: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/5)

So, is there any simple rule helping us to choose between `=` and `:=`? A possible summary is:

1. Don't abuse either of them.
2. Think about if the right hand side of `=`/`:=` **can** be evaluated instantly.
3. Think about if the right hand side of `=`/`:=` **should** be evaluated instantly.

---

Here are some examples to help you explore what's going on.

```
(* Symbol definitions: *)
Clear[f, x];
x = 1; f = x; x = 2;
f (* 1 *)

Clear[f, x];
x = 1; f := x; x = 2;
f (* 2 *)

(* Function definitions: *)
Clear[f, x];
x = 1; f[x_] = x; x = 2;
f[3] (* 1 *)

Clear[f, x];
x = 1; f[x_] := x; x = 2;
f[3] (* 3 *)

(* Set still pattern-matches if pattern names
   were present in the rhs at definition time: *)
Clear[f, x];
f[x_] = x; x = 2;
f[3] (* 3 *)
```

> **keywords:** set setdelayed assignment definition function variable

Comment: Nice! Perhaps the behavior of (for example)`f = Interpolation[Array[RandomInteger@1000 &, 1000]]` with `Set` and `SetDelayed`could be illustrative.

Answer (score 91):

### User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ

Frequently there are questions, to which the answer is to use `x_?NumericQ`, about defining functions that call or sometimes are passed to

- `FindRoot`, `NIntegrate`, `NMaximize`, `NMinimize`, `FindMaximum`, `FindMinimum`, `NDSolve`, `ParametricNDSolve`, `FindFit`, `LinearModelFit`, `NonlinearModelFit`, and so on.

Sometimes the analogous `VectorQ`, `MatrixQ`, or `ArrayQ` is the answer (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/numericq-equivalent-for-lists/19600#19600)).

The Wolfram Knowledge Base Article, "Using ?NumericQ to Affect Order of Evaluation" ([Wolfram version (dead link)](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820); [WayBack Machine version](https://web.archive.org/web/20140709133301/http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820)), gave a good explanation of how to use `NumericQ`; it has been replaced by ["How do I use ?NumericQ to affect order of evaluation?"](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502)

*Edit:* [This was anticipated over a year ago on Meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/candidate-topics-posts-for-canonical-questions/438#438).

#### Answers in which `NumericQ` figured

Here are links to some of the answers in which `NumericQ` was a key to the solution of the problem.
The headings include the command(s) and sometimes some error messages characteristic of this problem.

Some answers deal with multiple commands and they are not sorted into combinations, except `NIntegrate`/`FindRoot` which is a particularly common problem; connections with other functions indicated next to the links.

- **`NIntegrate`/`FindRoot`** —
  [1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16422/solving-integrals/16426#16426),
  [2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24704/is-it-possible-to-treat-starting-values-as-variables/24705#24705),
  [3) vector-valued functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89797/more-issues-integrate-nintegrate-findroot/89803#89803).
- **`FindRoot` - `FindRoot::nlnum`** —
  [1)`NArgMax`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/wrong-use-of-numberq/10404#10404),
  [2) `SingularValueList`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7551/find-determinant-or-row-reduce-parameter-dependent-matrix/7553#7553),
  [3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24399/finding-the-root-of-a-nested-function-with-small-values).
- **`NIntegrate` - `NIntegrate::inumr`, `NIntegrate::nlim`** —
  [1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15875/plot-holdall-and-the-color-problem/15876#15876),
  [2) and plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/plotting-multivariable-integration/9914#9914),
  [3) `Compile`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17993/using-a-compiled-function-inside-nintegrate-gives-compiledfunctioncfsa-messa/17994#17994),
  [4)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/how-do-i-prevent-nintegrateinumr-errors-within-other-functions/8900#8900),
  [5) `NDSolve`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/nintegrate-is-resetting-my-variables-and-not-giving-me-a-result/3641#3641),
  [6) nested `NIntegrate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135164/4999).
- **`NDSolve`** —
  [1a)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6751/optimization-problem-with-ndsolve/6764#6764),
  [1b)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6751/optimization-problem-with-ndsolve/6755#6755),
  [2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18932/using-dsolve-to-solve-for-xt-parameter/19053#19053),
  [3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25260/ndsolve-with-vector-function/25287#25287).
- **`NMinimize`/`NMaximize`/`FindMinimum`/`FindMaximum` - `NMinimize::nnum`, `FindMinimum::nrnum`** —
  [1) `NMinimize`/`NMaximize`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/333/combined-numerical-minimization-and-maximization/336#336),
  [2) `FindMinimum`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22210/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-nintegrate-inside-the-findminimum-function/22216#22216),
  [3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4002/minimizing-a-function-of-many-coordinates/4010#4010) explanation of the downside of `NumericQ`.
- **`FindFit`/`LinearModelFit`/`NonlinearModelFit`** —
  [1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10089/how-to-use-findfit-to-fit-an-implicit-function/10091#10091), [2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25905/121)
- **Plotting** — In earlier versions of *Mathematica*, various plotting functions first evaluated the function to be plotted *symbolically*, which would result in warnings. As of V9 or perhaps earlier, these warnings were no longer emitted. [As of V10.2, `ParametricPlot` seems to be an exception.]  [1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/plotting-multivariable-integration/9914#9914) [As of, at least v11.0, `RegionPlot3D` is also an exception.] [2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189717/regionplot-evaluating-nintegrate-before-assigning-variable-values-and-resulting)

Comment: There are many answers in which `NumericQ` figures.  Some have long explanations, some just point out the problem, and some show the solution without much comment.  Of the ones I could find, I tried to include those with at least some explanation and include a variety of the circumstances in which the problem arises.  No doubt others may know of better examples I've missed, and I hope they will improve this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't believe this wasn't already on the list.  Thanks for adding it, and with lots of references!

Comment: It looks like newer systems (version 10.3 at least) only issue a message but then continue with the calculation and return the right result, at least with the example from the Wolfram quick answer: `NMaximize[NIntegrate[(2 - a) Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}], a]`.

Comment: @BoLe  This is how it works in V8.0.4 and  V9.0.1, too.  One issue newbies seem to face is to distinguish warnings from fatal errors.  And, aside from their own uncertainty, maybe they need to show their boss/client/advisor/professor code that is red-message free to convince him or her that they're doing things right.

Answer (score 90):

### Understand what `Set` (=) really does

Because WRI's tutorials and documentation encourage the use of `=`, the infix operator version of `Set`, in a manner that mimics assignment in other programming languages, newcomers to *Mathematica* are likely to presume that `Set` is the equivalent of whatever kind of assignment operator they have previously encountered. It is hard but essential for them to learn that `Set` actually associates a rewrite rule (an ownvalue) with a symbol. This is a form of symbol binding unlike that in any other programming language in popular use, and eventually leads to shock, dismay, and confusion, when the new user evaluates something like `x = x[1]`

*Mathematica*'s built-in documentation doesn't do a good job of helping the new user to learn how different its symbol binding really is. The information is all there, but organized almost as if to hide rather than reveal the existence and significance of ownvalues.

What does it mean to say that "`Set` actually associates a rewrite rule (an ownvalue) with a symbol"? Let's look at what happens when an "assignment" is made to the symbol `a`; i.e., when `Set[a, 40 + 2]` is evaluated.

```
a = 40 + 2
```

> 42

The above is just `Set[a, 40 + 2]` as it is normally written. On the surface all we can see is that the sub-expression `40 + 2` was evaluated to 42 and returned, the binding of `a` to 42 is a side-effect. In a procedural language, `a` would now be associated with a chunk of memory containing the value 42. In *Mathematica* the side effect is to create a new rule called an ownvalue and to associate `a` with that rule. *Mathematica* will apply the rule whenever it encounters the symbol `a` as an atom.  *Mathematica*, being a pretty open system, will let us examine the rule.

```
OwnValues[a]
```

> {HoldPattern[a] :> 42}

To emphasize how really different this is from procedural assignment, consider

```
a = a[1]; a
```

> 42[1]

Surprised? What happened is the ownvalue we created above caused `a` to rewritten as 42 on the righthand side of the expression. Then *Mathematica* made a new ownvalue rule which it used to rewrite the `a` occurring after the semicolon as `42[1]`. Again, we can confirm this:

```
OwnValues[a]
```

> {HoldPattern[a] :> 42[1]}

An excellent and more detailed explanation of where *Mathematica* keeps symbol bindings and how it deals with them can be found in the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues). To find out more about this issue within *Mathematica*'s documentation [go here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SymbolHandling.html).

> **keywords** set assign ownvalue variable-binding

Comment: +1 But I think the sentence "It is hard but essential to them to learn that Set actually associates a rewrite rule (an ownvalue) with a symbol." deserves further explanation for a new user.

Comment: Not only does the documentation not do a good job of explaining how different *Mathematica* is to other languages, but in many cases actually attempts to hand-wave the differences away. A user can have read the documentation thoroughly, but then come to a site like this and realise they don't understand the language at all. For this reason I think resources like [Leonid's book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/Book.html) that deal with things more directly are really essential resources for the newcomer.

Comment: Consider adding a link to this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52) which explains the distinction between `OwnValues`, `DownValues`, etc.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The book Power Programming With Mathematica: The Kernel by David B. Wagner also does a good job with this issue.

Comment: @belisarius. I hope my latest edit supplies the additional explanation you asked for.

Comment: I think it's much better now!

Comment: What does a newcomer expect with he sees `a=a[1]`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this "deep" a level of explanation will so intimidate a Mathematica novice as to make him despair of ever understanding the language, will drive others away from Mathematica, and convince still others that they were right in thinking that to learn to use Mathematica productively is so hard they should stick with something that is seemingly more straightforward.

Comment: @Rojo. In the case that, say, `a[1] = 2` was previous evaluated, the novice will expect `a` to be bound to 2.

Comment: @m_goldberg I am still not understanding... what sequence of commands, starting from a cleared `a`, do you mean?

Comment: `a[1] = 2;a = 42;a = a[1]; a`

Comment: Which programming language assigns 2 to *a* with the syntax `a[1] = 2`? If I had no idea at all about Mathematica I'd assume that the `[1]` is an array subscript, and that the array member `a[1]` would be assigned. Which is just as wrong, but certainly very different from assigning `a`. Especially, I'd never expect the sequence `a = 42; a = a[1];` to give any meaningful result, no matter how much or little I knew about Mathematica.

Comment: @m_goldberg it's interesting to note that `f := a` creates an `OwnValue` as well. I suspect it is the presence of a pattern on the lhs which determines whether it is an `OwnValue` or a `DownValue`/`SubValue`.

Comment: @rcollyer. I think what you suspect is very likely the case. It certainly seems entirely reasonable to me.

Comment: Could you explain how to actually do what was intended `a=a[1]` to do? All this answer says is that it doesn't do what we expect, not how to do what we expect...

Comment: @Mehrdad. The point of this answer is that "what you expect" violates _Mathematica_ semantics. You must avoid constructs like `a=a[1]`

Comment: After reading paragraph #4, why shouldn't one ask why the rule for `a` isn't used on the left-hand side of `a=a[1]` as well? But this is because of the `HoldFirst` attribute of `Set` I suspect.

Answer (score 86):

## Learn how to use the Documentation Center effectively

*Mathematica* comes with the most comprehensive documentation I have ever seen in a software product. This documentation contains

- *reference pages* for every *Mathematica* function
- *tutorials* for various topics, which show you step by step how to achieve something
- *guide pages* to give you an overview of functions about a specific topic
- a categorised *function navigator*, to help you find appropriate *guide pages* and *reference pages*.
- finally, the complete interactive *Mathematica book*

You can always open the Documentation Center by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>. When the cursor (the I-beam) is anywhere near a function, then the help page of this function is opened. E.g. when your cursor is anywhere at the position where the dots are in `.I.n.t.e.g.r.a.t.e.`, you will be directed to the help page of `Integrate`.

### Reference pages:

A *reference page* is a help page which is dedicated to exactly one *Mathematica* function (or symbol).
In the image below you see the reference page of the `Sin` function. Usually, some of the sections are open, but here I closed them so you see all parts at once.

[image]

- In **yellow**, you see the **usage**. It gives you instantly information about how many arguments the function expects. Often there is more then one usage. Additionally, a short description is given.
- The **Details** section gives you further information about `Options`, behavioural details and things which are important to note. In general, this section is only important in a more advanced state.
- In some cases, extra information is provided on the mathematical **Background** of the function explaining the depths of the method, its relation to other functions and its limitations (for example [`FindHamiltonianCycle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianCycle.html)).
- The **Examples** section is the most important, because there you have a lot of examples, showing everything starting from simple use cases to very advanced things. Study this section carefully!
- **See Also** gives you a list of functions which are related. Very helpful, when a function does not exactly what you want, because most probably you find help in the referenced pages.
- **Tutorials** shows you tutorials which are related to the function. In the case of `Sin` it is e.g. the *Elementary Transcendental Functions* tutorial.
- **Related Guides** gives you a list of related guide pages.
- **Related Links** references to material in the web: Demonstrations, *MathWorld* pages, etc.

In general my recommendation for viewing a help page is the following:

1. Study the usage carefully
2. Look up basic examples. If you don't find what you need, look up *all* examples
3. Read the *Details*

And of course if you like the how-to style, you should read the referenced tutorials.

### Guide pages:

Guide pages collect all functions which belong to a certain topic and they are an excellent resource when you try to find a function you do not know yet.

[image]

The guide page itself is often divided into several subsections collecting similar functions. In the image above for instance the *Trigonometric Functions*. Furthermore, you can find links to tutorials, etc. when you open the **Learning Resources** tab. At the end of each guide page you will find references to related guide pages.

### Function navigator and virtual book:

The rest can be explored by just trying and does not need extensive explanation. To reach the function navigator or the book, you can use the buttons on the top of the Documentation Center.

[image]

The rest is mostly self-explanatory. The virtual book is a very nice resource when you like to read something from the beginning to the end. In this way you can be sure that you at least scraped every functionality of *Mathematica*, which you probably miss when you hop between the help pages. But be warned, it is a lot of material!

### Final notes:

- Since the complete documentation consists of usual *Mathematica* notebooks, all calculations and examples can be tested inside the help pages. Of course, you cannot destroy the documentation, because everything is reset when you close a help page.
- You can always search the documentation by typing into the search bar on top of the Documentation Center:

  [image]
- I often find it convenient to browse through the entire contents of a specific documentation page, or to use Mathematica's find function (<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to search it.  However, doing so requires that all the cells be opened; and since some of the documentation pages can have many cells (Plot has 50), it can be tedious to open them one-at-a-time.  Thus, to open them all at once, L-click anywhere in the documentation page, use <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the cells, and then use <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to open them.  [Note: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> for Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for Windows and Linux.]
- When coming from a different programming language, and you are not sure that a certain *Mathematica* function is equivalent to what you are used to, be sure to check the **Properties & Relations** section in the reference page to get ideas on what other functions could be relevant for your case.

Comment: F1 works only on Windows and Linux. Documentation Center is accessed on a Mac using command-shift-F.

Comment: @rhomboidRhipper I use *Mathematica* on two MacBooks Pro and on several MacPro's and on each of them the F1 short-cut is working fine. Is it possible that your system settings required that you need to press a the command shift combination to access the F keys?

Comment: It should be noted that the V10 documentation works differently. The home page is different and currently the function navigator is missing.

Comment: Is it just me, or are there fewer good tutorials on how to use features than there used to be many years ago, now the style seems to be to give a collection of functions related to the feature and little exposition on how to use them other than in the applications section of the function?

Comment: @image_doctor, to this day, I still vastly prefer the pre-version 6 tree-style arrangement of the docs; to me, it encouraged the exploration of functions that can be related to what you were looking for.

Answer (score 83):

### Assuming commands will have side effects when they don't

Consider:

```
In[97]:= list = {1, 2, 3}
Out[97]= {1, 2, 3}

In[98]:= Append[list, 4]
Out[98]= {1, 2, 3, 4}

In[99]:= list
Out[99]= {1, 2, 3}
```

When I was first learning *Mathematica*, I assumed that `Append[list, 4]` would take the list `list` and append the element `4` to it, overwriting the previous list. But this is not right: `Append[]` returns the result of appending `4` to `list` **without** overwriting the input `list`.

However, there is [`AppendTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html) with the desired side effect

```
In[100]:= list = {1, 2, 3}
Out[100]= {1, 2, 3}

In[101]:= AppendTo[list, 4]
Out[101]= {1, 2, 3, 4}

In[102]:= list
Out[102]= {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

In general, a command which alters its inputs, or other global variables, is said to have a [side effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29). *Mathematica* in general avoids side effects whenever it would be reasonable to do so, encouraging (but not forcing) a [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style, **returning values instead of variables** (addresses/pointers/names/etc. in other languages). If one wants to store a value (instead of passing it right away to another function) one has to "save" it explicitly into a variable.

I think it is a safe statement that the *Mathematica* documentation will always say explicitly when a command has a side effect. For example, the documentation (version 7) for `Delete[]` reads

> `Delete[expr,n]` deletes the element at position $n$ in $expr$.

If I encountered this sentence in the documentation of a language I had never seen before, I would assume that `Delete[]` altered the expression `expr`. However, with experience reading *Mathematica* documentation, I am confident that if this side effect existed, it would be stated explicitly and, indeed, `Delete[]` has no side effects.

I remember finding many of the list commands confusing because their names are verbs which, in English, would seem to suggest that the list was being restructured. In particular, note that `Append[]`, `Prepend[]`, `Take[]`, `Drop[]`, `Insert[]`, `Delete[]`, `Replace[]`, `ReplacePart[]`, `DeleteDuplicates[]`, `Flatten[]`, `Join[]`, `Transpose[]`, `Reverse[]` and `Sort[]` are all side effect free.

For completeness, I should mention that for some functions there are side-effect-having alternatives, usually with an added prefix at the end of the function name, like `AppendTo` (for `Append`), `AddTo` (for `Add`), `SubtractFrom` (for `Subtract`), `TimesBy` (for `Times`), etc. These functions not only perform the calculation but also save the new result into the variable they were called with. Because of this, they **must** be called with a symbol instead of a number or an explicit list.

Comment: "Special forms of assignment" :http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialFormsOfAssignment.html

Comment: Would the "...prefix at the end..." be a postfix?

Comment: @mikuszefski (and DavidSpeyer), I think 'suffix' is the more common English word.

Comment: Well, sort of... @JadeNB for further reading [english SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81263/postfix-or-suffix)

Comment: Maybe it should be mentioned that `AppendTo` can take quite a bit of time, especially for long lists. It's definitely not a constant-time operation, as in other languages.

Answer (score 79):

### Lingering Definitions: when calculations go bad

One aspect of *Mathematica* that sometimes confuses new users, and has confused me often enough, is the *Lingering Definition Problem*. *Mathematica* diligently **accumulates all definitions** (functions, variables, etc.) during a session, and they remain in effect in the memory **until explicitly cleared/removed**. Here's a quick experiment you can do, to see the problem clearly.

1: Launch (or re-launch) *Mathematica*, create a new notebook, and evaluate the following expression:

```
x = 2 + 2
```

[image: x = 2 + 2]

2: Now close the notebook document without saving (and without quitting *Mathematica*), and create another fresh notebook. Evaluate this:

```
x
```

[image: x]

The result can be surprising to beginners - after all, you think you've just removed all visible traces of `x`, closing the only notebook with any record of it, and yet, it still exists, and still has the value 4.

To explain this, you need to know that when you launch the *Mathematica* application, you're launching two linked but separate components: the visible *front-end*, which handles the notebooks and user interaction, and the invisible *kernel*, which is the programming engine that underpins the *Mathematica* system. The notebook interface is like the flight deck or operating console, and the kernel is like the engine, hidden away but ready to provide the necessary power.

So, what happened when you typed the expression `x = 2 + 2`, is that the **front-end** sent it to the **kernel** for evaluation, and received the result back from the kernel for display. The resulting symbol, and its value, is now part of the kernel. You can close documents and open new ones, but the kernel's knowledge of the symbol `x` is unaffected, until something happens to change that.

And it's these lingering definitions that can confuse you - symbols that are not visible in your current notebook *are still present and defined* in the kernel, and might affect your current evaluations.

This also affects subscripted expressions - consider the following evaluation, where the initially innocent symbol `i` is assigned an explicit value:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to use subscripted symbols in a more robust fashion, you should use e.g. the [Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html).

There are a couple of things you can learn to do to avoid problems caused by Lingering Definitions. Before you provide definitions for specific symbols, clear any existing values that you've defined so far in the session, with the `Clear` function.

```
Clear[x]
```

Or you can clear all symbols in the global context, using `ClearAll`.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

When all else fails, quit the kernel (choose **Evaluation** > **Quit Kernel** from the menu or type `Quit[]`, thereby forgetting all the symbols (and everything else) that you've defined in the kernel.

Some further notes:

- *Mathematica* offers a way to keep the namespaces of your notebooks separate, so that they don't share the same symbols ([see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/853/is-there-a-way-to-separate-variables-between-multiple-notebooks)).
- *Mathematica* does have garbage collection, but most of the time you don't have to care about it being completely automatic.
- Some dynamic variables can remain in effect even if the kernel is quit, as such variables are owned by the frontend. Be sure to remove all generated dynamic cells (via the menu option **Cell** > **Delete All Ouput**) before quitting/restarting the kernel.
- See also this Q&A: [How do I clear all user defined symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols)

Comment: Thought I'd have a go at something basic.

Comment: I'd mention that the notebooks can be logically separated by setting their [default contexts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/853/52) to something other than ``Global` ``.

Comment: +1 I'd like more a title like "Lingering definitions: Why your notebook calcs may return weird results", which links the problem with the perceived symptoms

Comment: I added a bit about subscript issues, not sure if it should be a separate answer, but it fits nicely into the scope of this one...

Comment: Another important part of this separation is that saving the notebook only saves what is shown, not the values of symbols defined in it. So if you save the notebook with the definition of `x` and then open it again in a new Mathematica session, you might expect to be able to immediately use `x` again in the notebook. But you can't do that, you first have to evaluate the definition again.

Comment: BTW, another way lingering definitions can bite you is when you change the pattern part of a function definition as well as the corresponding code part by editing the notebook and then executing the cell, but failing to first `Clear` the old version. Then you don't overwrite the definition, but *add* a new one, and it may happen that one of your calls happens to better fit the old version. Bugs of that type are *very* hard to find because all traces of the actually executed code have been removed from the notebook by the edit.

Answer (score 79):

### Attempting to make an assignment to the argument of a function

Quite frequently new users attempt something like this:

```
foo[bar_, new_] := AppendTo[bar, new]

x = {1};

foo[x, 2]
```

To be met with:

> AppendTo::rvalue: {1} is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed. >>

Or:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x = x + y; x)

a = 1;
b = 2;

f[a, b]
```

> Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1. >>

This is because the *value* of the symbol `x`, `a`, etc. is inserted into the right-hand-side definition.

One needs either a [Hold attribute](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldFirst.html) for in-place modification:

```
SetAttributes[foo, HoldFirst]

foo[bar_, new_] := AppendTo[bar, new]

x = {1};

foo[x, 2];

x
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

Or a temporary symbol, typically created with [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html), for intermediate calculations:

```
f[x_, y_] := Module[{t}, t = x + y; t]

a = 1;
b = 2;

f[a, b]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

(This definition is of course highly contrived for such a simple operation.)

Other Hold attributes include: `HoldAll`, `HoldRest`, and `HoldAllComplete`.

For some more details, see also [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/how-to-modify-function-argument/).

---

Note: Passing held arguments to a function with Attributes is similar to passing arguments by reference in other languages; ByRef keyword in VBA, or passing a pointer or a reference in C++ for example. However note that this similarity is no equivalence; for example, when passing the first element of a list to a reference in C++, only the list member will be passed; in Mathematica, the *expression to access* the list member will be passed. This can lead to differences if e.g. another item is prepended to the list before accessing the argument: With pass by reference in C++, the argument will refer to the same value, despite it now being the *second* element; however Mathematica will evaluate the expression only after using the argument, thus giving the new first element:

```
a={1,2,3};
SetAttributes[foo, HoldFirst]
foo[x_] := (PrependTo[a, 0]; x)
foo[ a[[1]] ]
(*
==> 0
*)
```

Comment: Passing held arguments to a function with Attributes is similar to passing arguments by reference in other languages.

Comment: @Faysal If you feel that should be part of the answer feel free to edit it.  I'm quite unfamiliar with most other languages so I'll not do that myself.

Comment: Surprising from someone of your level !

Comment: @Wizard +1 although I am highly surprised that no answer that I read so far on this post explained the importance of Hold, HoldAll and HoldFirst etc.. I remember Michael Trott mentioning how critical is to the understanding of any Mathematica user

Answer (score 68):

### Understand the difference between exact and approximate (Real) numbers

Unlike many other computational software, *Mathematica* allows you to deal with exact integers and rational numbers (heads `Integer` and `Rational`), as well as normal floating-point (`Real`) numbers.  While you can use both exact and floating-point numbers in a calculation, using exact quantities where they aren’t required can slow computations down.

Also, mixing the data types up in a single list will mess up [packed arrays](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/391/).

The different data types are represented differently by *Mathematica*. This means, for example, that integer zero  (`0`) and real zero (`0.`) only equal numerically (`0 == 0.` yields `True`) but not structurally (`0 === 0.` yields `False`). In certain cases [you have to test for both](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13459/8) or you will run into trouble. And you have to make sure that `List` index numbers (i.e. the arguments to `Part`) are [exact integers not real numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15830/8).

As with any computer language, calculations with real numbers is not exact and will accumulate error. As a consequence, your real-valued calculation might not necessarily return zero even when you think it should. There may be small (less than $10^{-10}$) remainders, which might even be complex valued.  If so, you can use `Chop` to get rid of these. Furthermore, you can carry over the small numerical error, unnoticed:

```
Floor[(45.3 - 45)*100] - 30   (* ==> -1 instead of 0 *)
```

In such cases, use exact rational numbers instead of reals:

```
Floor[(453/10 - 45)*100] - 30  (* ==> 0 *)
```

Sometimes, if you are doing a calculation containing some zeros and some approximate real numbers, as well as algebraic expressions, you will end up with approximate zeros multiplied by the algebraic elements in the result. But of course you want them to cancel out, right? Again, use `Chop`, that removes small real numbers close to zero (smaller than $10^{-10}$ according to the default tolerance level).

Some solvers (`Solve`, `Reduce`, `Integrate`, `DSolve`, `Minimize`, etc.) try to find exact solutions.  They work better with exact numbers for coefficients and powers.  As just mentioned, if approximate real numbers are used, terms that should cancel out might not, and the solver might fail to find a solution.  Other solvers (`NSolve`, `FindRoot`, `NIntegrate`, `NDSolve`, `NMinimize`, `FindMinimum`, etc.) try to find approximate solutions.  Generally they work well with either exact or approximate numbers.  However, some of them do symbolic analysis and sometimes perform better with functions or equations that are given in terms of exact numbers.

> **keywords:** real integer number-type machine-precision

Comment: Not sure how, but it I guess it would be nice to add that you can add floating-point numbers with greater precision in order to improve results. Something like "45.3`30" might improve upon the result described here...

Comment: @ivbc And then there's ``Floor[(1/45.`30)*45] - 1`` -- every example contrived to illustrate a limitation as a fix, but that does not mean the fix does not have a similar limitation. However, I agree that a reference to full range of numbers would be helpful, such as the tech note [***Numbers***](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html).

Answer (score 64):

## The displayed form may substantially differ from the internal form

As soon as you discover replacement rules, you are bound to find that they mysteriously fail to replace subexpressions, or replace subexpressions you didn't expect to be replaced.

For example, consider the definition

```
foo = (a+b)(c+d)(e-f)/Sqrt[2]
```

which will cause Mathematica output an expression which looks very much like what you entered; approximately:
$$\frac{(a+b)(c+d)(e-f)}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Also the `InputForm` seems to confirm that no transformation has been done to that expression:

```
((a + b)*(c + d)*(e - f))/Sqrt[2]
```

Now try to apply some rules on this (from now on I'll give the output in InputForm):

```
foo /. {x_ + y_ -> x^2 + y^2, x_ - y_ -> x^2 - y^2, Sqrt[2] -> Sqrt[8]}
(*
==> ((a^2 + b^2)*(c^2 + d^2)*(e^2 + f^2))/Sqrt[2]
*)
```

What is that? We explicitly requested the difference to be replaced with a *difference* of squares, not a sum! And why wasn't `Sqrt[2]` replaced at all?

Well, the reason is that Mathematica expressions are not what they look like. To see the *real* structure of a Mathematica expression, you can use `FullForm`:

```
foo // FullForm
(*
==> Times[Power[2, Rational[-1, 2]], Plus[a, b], Plus[c, d], 
     Plus[e, Times[-1, f]]]
*)
```

Now, we see why the replacement rules didn't work as expected: `e-f` is actually `e + (-1)*f` and thus matched perfectly the first rule (sum of two expressions) which transformed that into `e^2 + ((-1)*f)^2` which of course evaluates to `e^2+f^2`. At the time the second rule is applied, the difference doesn't exist any more. Also, the `Sqrt[2]` in the denominator is actually a *factor* of `2^(-1/2)`. It is also easy to check that `Sqrt[2]` has `Power[2, Rational[1, 2]]` (that is, `2^(1/2)`) as `FullForm`. That one is nowhere found in the `FullForm` of the expression `foo` evaluates to.

With that knowledge we can correct our replacement rules to work as expected:

```
foo /. {x_Symbol + y_Symbol -> x^2 + y^2,
        x_Symbol - y_Symbol -> x^2 - y^2,
        1/Sqrt[2] -> 1/Sqrt[8]}
(*
==> ((a^2 + b^2)*(c^2 + d^2)*(e^2 - f^2))/(2*Sqrt[2])
*)
```

First, we restricted our `+` rule to only accept symbols as expressions, so that it doesn't match `e-f`. For consistency, the same is true for the second rule. Finally, we replaced `1/Sqrt[2]` instead of `Sqrt[2]` (Mathematica correctly evaluated `1/Sqrt[8]` to `1/(2 Sqrt[2])`).

Note that instead of `FullForm` you can also use `TreeForm`, which gives you a nice graphical representation of the internal expression).

#### Two common examples

*Complex numbers*

An example of this that shows up quite often is when matching expressions with complex numbers. Some common examples are the following:

```
Cases[-I, I, Infinity]
(* { } *)
Cases[2 I, I, Infinity]
(* { } *)
```

The reason why `I` appears nowhere in those expressions is revealed when we look at the `FullForm` of the expressions:

```
I // FullForm
(* Complex[0, 1] *)
-I // FullForm
(* Complex[0, -1] *)
1 + 2 I // FullForm
(* Complex[1, 2] *)
```

All of these expressions are *atoms*; that is, they are all considered indivisible (structureless) objects in *Mathematica* (at least as far as pattern-matching is concerned).

Different fixes are useful for different use cases, of course. If one wants to manually conjugate a symbolic expression, one can do

```
expr /. z_Complex :> Conjugate[z]
```

If one wants to treat `I` as a symbol rather than as a complex number, one can do

```
Clear@i
expr /. Complex[a_, b_] :> a + i b
```

The moral is as above: it is often useful to look at the `FullForm` of an expression in order to design patterns for matching subexpressions.

*Powers in the denominator*

Consider the following:

[image]

The reason that the denominator gets replaced in the second case but not the first is revealed by looking at the `FullForm`s of the expressions:

[image]

In the first case, the expression is *internally represented* with a negative power, but it is *displayed* as being the denominator of a fraction. Thus, the pattern `_^2` is not matched, and so the expression is not replaced.

Comment: A very common mistake, indeed (+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I were able, I would upvote it ten times not just one

Answer (score 58):

### Don't leave the Suggestions Bar enabled

The predictive interface (Suggestions Bar) is the source of many bugs reported on this site and surely many more that have yet to be reported.  I strongly suggest that all new users [turn off the Suggestions Bar](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12406) to avoid unexpected problems such as massive memory usage(**[[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71889/121)**, **[[2]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173521/121)**), peculiar evaluation leaks (**[[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66037/121)**, **[[2]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128244/280)**), [broken assignments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105552/121), [disappearing definitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124005/121), and crashes(**[[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137211/121)**, **[[2]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172622/121)**).

[image: how to turn it off]

Comment: I remember I was at one of Wolfram summer schools, and during the first lecture on Mathematica fundamentals the lecturer said something like "The first thing you should do when you get you first copy of Mathematica is to go the Preferences and disable the Suggestions Bar".

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Version 11 is supposed to have an improved interface. Hopefully they polish this feature.

Comment: Nope, they didn't: It causes disastrous kernel issues on my Win 7 x64 installation, see my post "Mma11 on Windows: Forgetful kernel?" Typical Wolfram...

Comment: @Pirx I added a link to your Q&A from this post; it's a great example of the crazy problems still present.  That shouldn't have made it out of alpha, let alone final release!

Answer (score 56):

### Multiple front-end *undo* is not available in versions less than 10

It is not possible to *undo* more than once in Mathematica 9 and earlier. Nevertheless, inside a single cell one can *undo* as long as one stays inside.

Recommendations to avoid trouble:

1. Never delete code except if what you were doing was completely
   wrong.
2. If you want to create a notebook for presentation, generate an additional file as a sandbox for testing purposes.

### Kernel *undo* is still not available

Starting from version 10, multiple-undo is available. However, it is important to keep in mind that this is a front-end undo, not a kernel one. Thus, defining something like:

```
x:=4
Clear[x]
```

and then undoing the clear will not actually change the value of `x` back to 4.

Comment: Re Personal recommendation 2: Give your sandbox a separate context, as described here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3484/1200 , so that definitions from the Sandbox don't leak into the presentation.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Good recommendation. This is something I should keep in mind!

Answer (score 49):

### Mathematica's own programming model: functions and expressions

There are many books about *Mathematica* programming, still one sees many people falling to understand *Mathematica*'s programming model and usually misunderstand it as *functional programming*.

This is, because one can pass a *function* as an argument, like

```
plotZeroPi[f_] := Plot[f[x], {x,0,Pi}];
plotZeroPi[Sin] (* produces Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,Pi}] *)
```

and so people tend to think that *Mathematica* follows a functional programming (FP) model. There is even a section in the documentation about [functional Programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html). Yes, looks similar, but it is different - and you will see shortly why.

#### Expressions are what evaluation is about

Everything in *Mathematica* is an [expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html). An expression can be an atom, like numbers, symbol variables and other built-in atoms, or a compound expression. Compound expressions -our topic here- have a *head* followed by arguments between square brackets, like `Sin[x]`.

Thus, evaluation in *Mathematica* is the [ongoing transformation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PrinciplesOfEvaluation.html) from one expression to another based on certain *rules*, user-defined and built-in, until no rules are applicable. That last expression is returned as the answer.

*Mathematica* derives its power from this simple concept, plus a lot of syntactic sugar you have to write expressions in a more concise way… and something more we will see below. We don't intend to explain all the details here, as there are other sections in this guide to help you.

In fact, what happened above is the definition of a new *head*, `plotZeroPi` via the infix operator `:=`. More over, the first argument is a *pattern expression* `plotZeroPi[f_]`, with head (as pattern) `plotZeroPi` and a pattern argument. The notation `f_` simply introduces an *any* pattern and gives it a name, `f`, which we use in the right hand side **as the head of another expression**.

That's why a common way to express what `f` is, is that `plotZeroPi` has a function argument - although is not very precise-, and we also say that `plotZeroPi` is a *function* (or a high-level function in FP lingo), although is now clear that there is a little abuse of the terminology here.

Bottom line: ***Mathematica* looks like functional programming because one is able to define and pass around heads.**

#### Putting evaluation on hold

But, note that `Plot` does not expect a function, it expects a expression! So, although in a functional programming paradigm, one would write `Plot` with a *function* parameter, in *Mathematica* plot expects an expression. This was a design choice in *Mathematica* and one that I would argue makes it quite readable.

This works because `Plot` is flagged to *hold* the evaluation of its arguments (see [non-standard](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html)). Once `Plot` sets its environment internally, it triggers the evaluation of the expression with specific values assigned to `x`. When you read the documentation, beware of this subtlety: it says *function* although a better term would have been *expression*.

#### Dynamically creating a head

So, what happens if one needs to perform a complex operation and once that is done, a function is clearly defined? Say you want to compute `Sin[`$\alpha$ `x]`, where $\alpha$ is the result of a complex operation. A naive approach is

```
func[p_, x_] := Sin[costlyfunction[p] x]
```

If you then try

```
Plot[func[1.,x], {x,0,Pi}]
```

you can be waiting long to get that plot. Even this does not work

```
func[p_][x_] := Sin[costlyfunction[p] x]
```

because the whole expression is unevaluated when entering `Plot` anyway. In fact, if you try func[1.] in the front-end, you will see that *Mathematica* does not know a rule about it and can't do much either.

What you need is something that allows you to return a **head** of an expression. That thing will have `costlyfunction` calculated once before `Plot` takes your head (the expression's, not yours) and gives it an `x`.

*Mathematica* has a built-in, `Function` that gives you that.

```
func[p_] := With[{a = costlyfunction[p]}, Function[x, Sin[a x]] ];
```

`With` introduces a new context where that costly function is evaluated and assigned to `a`. That value is remembered by `Function` as it appears as a local symbol in its definition. `Function` is nothing but a *head* that you can use when needed. For those familiar with functional programming in other languages, `a` is part of the *closure* where the `Function` is defined; and `Function` is the way one enters a *lambda* construct into *Mathematica*.

Another way to do it, more imperative if you like, is using `Module` and what you already know about defining rules -which is more familiar to [procedural programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProceduralProgramming.html)-:

```
func[p_] := Module[{f, a},
    a = costlyfunction[p];
    f[x_] := Sin[a x];
    f
    ];
```

In it, a new context is introduced with two symbols, `f` and `a`; and what it does is simple: it calculates `a`, then defines `f` as a **head** as we want it, and finally returns that symbol `f` as answer, a newly created head you can use in the caller.

In this definition, when you try say, func[1.], you will see a funny symbol like `f$3600` being returned. This is the symbol that has the rule `f[x_] := Sin[a x]` attached to it. It was created by `Module` to isolate any potential use of `f` from the outside world. It works, but certainly is not as idiomatic as `function`.

The approach with `Function` is more direct, and there is syntactic sugar for it too; you will see it in regular *Mathematica* programming

```
func[p_] := With[{a = costlyfunction[p]}, Sin[a #]& ];
```

Ok, let's continue.

Now that `func` really returns a *function*, i.e. something that you can use as the head of an expression. You would use it with `Plot` like

```
With[{f = func[1.]}, Plot[f[x],{x,0,Pi}]]
```

and we bet that by this time you will understand why `Plot[func[1.][x],{x,0,Pi}]` is as bad as any of the previous examples.

#### On returning an expression

A final example is `Piecewise` (from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html))

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}], {x, -2, 2}]
```

So, what if the boundary on the condition is a parameter? Well, just apply the recipe above:

```
paramPieces[p_] := Piecewise[{{#^2, # < p}, {#, # > p}}] &;
```

One shouldn't do

```
paramPieces[p_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, x < p}, {x, x > p}}];
```

because `Piecewise` does not have the *hold* attribute and it will try to evaluate its argument. It does not expect an expression! If `x` is not defined, you may see a nice output when you use it, but now you are constrained to use the atom (variable name) `x` and although

```
Plot[paramPieces[0], {x, -1, 1}]
```

seems to work, you are setting yourself for trouble. So, how to return something you can use in `Plot`?

Well, in this case, the parameter is not a burden to the calculation itself, so one sees this kind of definitions being used

```
paramPieces[p_, x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, x < p}, {x, x > p}}];
Plot[paramPieces[0, x], {x,-1,1}]
```

And, if x is undefined, `paramPieces[0, x]` is nicely displayed in the front-end as before. This works because, again, *Mathematica* is a *expressions language*, and the parameter `x` makes as much sense as the number `1.23` in the definition of `paramPieces`. As said, *Mathematica* just stops the evaluation of `paramPieces[0, x]` when no more rules are applied.

#### A remark on assignment

We have said above several times that `x` gets assigned a value inside `Plot` and so on. Again, beware this is not the same as variable assignment in functional programming and certainly there is (again) abuse of language for the sake of clarity.

What one has in *Mathematica* is a new rule that allows the evaluation loop to replace all occurrences of `x` by a value. As an appetizer, the following works

```
Plot3D[Sin[x[1] + x[2]], {x[1], -Pi, Pi}, {x[2], -Pi, Pi}]
```

There is no *variable* `x[1]`, just a expression that gets a new rule(s) inside `Plot` every time it gets a value for plotting. You can read more about this in [this guide](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18456/193) too.

**Note to readers:** Although these guides are not meant to be comprehensive, please, feel free to leave comments to help improve them.

Comment: I have heard Mathematica being called a multi paradigm language.

Comment: +1 I believe that once you understand the Mathematica evaluation and the use of With you can do almost anything with Mathematica.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom, I've heard the same, so I will add some notes to reach a wider audience. Thanks!

Comment: But in *Mathematica* everything is an expression, so it's not wrong to call a function an expression.

Comment: An easy way to understand Mathematica's evaluation: consider a function/tree f[a,b]. Without any particular attribute for f the leafs/arguments will be evaluated before the parent f. With f having a HoldAll attribute you don't evaluate the leafs but go directly in the evaluation of f. a and b will be evaluated as soon as they are used in a function that doesn't hold again their evaluation. Example SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]; f[a_,b_]:= a Hold[b]; f[2^2,2^2]

Comment: Holding evaluation allows to destructure arguments and modify them before evaluation SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]; f[h_[b_]]:={h,b}; f[g[2]]

Comment: In fact a Hold attribute is not needed for destructuring as a DownValues definition for f already uses HoldPattern

Comment: Shouldn't your repeated references to the built-in named `function` actually be to `Function` (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)?

Comment: Shouldn't each instance of "function" be changed to "Function" above?

Comment: "Everything in Mathematica is an expression" - not `Dataset`, which has its own type system under the hood and doesn't work with external pattern matching and replacement.

Comment: @TedErsek, thanks, amended.

Comment: @alancalvitti, it means that `Dataset` is treated like an _atom_ for the evaluation loop, with some sort of special operators, right?

Comment: The link to "Functional Programming" is broken.

Comment: I like the remark that MMA “takes your head (the expression's, not yours).” I'm undecided yet whether or not I'm fully agree with the parenthesized restriction.

Comment: @alancalvitti There are many heads that are treated as atoms, `SparseArray` is the prime example, but `Dataset`, `Audio`, and other _large things_ have this property. Their content better not be stored in the expression, but instead refer to an efficient internal data structure. `Dataset` and `Audio` can even be loaded into memory only partially, as needed, and swapped out to temporary files under memory pressure. This does not contradict the “everything is an expression” statement: `2` is an atomic expression, too. A finite expression tree has to end with terminal atomic leaves, obviously.

Answer (score 45):

### Use Consistent Naming Conventions

This is basic, and good practice in any programming language, but Mathematica's slow-to-fail nature makes it in a sense a less forgiving language than others, so those of us who have in the past gotten away with bad habits may run into trouble. Suppose I have a function

```
loseMemoriesLikeTearsInRain[]
```

which I later try to invoke thusly:

```
loseMemoryLikeTearsInRain[]
```

In some other languages this would result in a compile error, and is easily spotted, but in Mathematica, what usually happens is either

1. the unevaluated expression `loseMemoryLikeTearsInRain[]` gets passed on to some other function,
2. Mathematica silently moves on without performing the side effects the function is supposed to perform, or
3. both.

For this reason, I have found it especially important to have a consistent set of conventions for naming things. The exact choice is to some extent a matter of taste, but here are some things that have tripped me up:

1. inconsistent capitalization,
2. starting function names with a capital letter (can conflict with predefined Mathematica functions),
3. inconsistent use of singular and plural (I now try to favor the singular whenever possible),
4. names that do not distinguish between pure functions and those with side effects (I now use noun-clauses and verb-clauses respectively),
5. generally inconsistent, idiosyncratic, or poorly thought out use of terminology,
6. attempts to abbreviate beyond what is reasonable or memorable. (One consistent convention is to drop all vowels other than the first letter of the word, whch mks evrythng lk lk ths.)

Comment: Autocompletion is useful for this purpose

Comment: Concerning Mathematica, I would not recommend abbreviating function names. Lengthy function names isn't really a big issue performance-wise, and in my experience it is more important that you remember years later what your function does than to save some typing. Mathematica itself is very eminent on giving informative though long names (think of `FrequencySamplingFilterKernel`, `SymmetrizedIndependentComponents`, etc.).

Comment: @István As a proponent of terse coding I do not fully agree.  For library functions that are used many times it saves considerable typing, even with auto-completion, to use short names, and the purpose of the function is unlikely to be forgotten.  For one-off functions I strongly prefer including a description of the function in a Text cell and for global functions a usage Message to long function names or in-line comments, in most cases.  Perhaps such coding style is worthy of a community wiki?  It would be interesting to have an exhibit of different styles to compare I think.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sure, you're right about using shortcut names (I do that myself a lot during development), but since this thread is mostly for new users, I think it's useful for them to stick to telltale function names. I'm afraid a coding-style wiki (though might be interesting) would fall into the fuzzy, "personal taste"-type questions. At least I know that my style has changed a lot during the years...

Answer (score 45):

### The default `$HistoryLength` causes Mathematica to crash!

By default `$HistoryLength = Infinity`, which is absurd. That ensures Mathematica will crash after making output with graphics or images for a few hours. Besides, who would do something like `In[2634]:=Expand[Out[93]]`.... You can ensure a reasonable default setting by including (`$HistoryLength=3`), or setting it to some other small integer in your "Init.m" file.

Comment: Is it similar if one quits the kernel from time to time? I'm putting my computer to sleep without closing Mathematica.

Comment: @Bole, I am not sure what the answer to your question is, But I often have Mathematica crash if I leave it running more than 24 hours with Dynamic output (e.g.  Manipulate).

Answer (score 42):

### Using `Sort` incorrectly

#### Sorting mathematical expressions without numeric conversion

New users are often baffled by the behavior of [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) on lists of mathematical expressions.  Though this is covered in the documentation of `Sort` itself they expect that expressions will be ordered by numeric value but they are not.  Instead expressions are effectively ordered with [`Order`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Order.html) which compares expression structures.  (The full details of that ordering [remain undisclosed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31261/121) but any specific pairing can be tested with `Order`.)

To sort a list of expressions by their numerical values one should use [`NumericalSort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericalSort.html), or somewhat more verbosely [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) or [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html).

```
exp = {Sqrt[2], 5, Sin[4]}

Sort[exp]
NumericalSort[expr]
SortBy[exp, N]
exp[[Ordering @ N @ exp]]
```

> ```
> {5, Sqrt[2], Sin[4]}
>
> {Sin[4], Sqrt[2], 5}
>
> {Sin[4], Sqrt[2], 5}
>
> {Sin[4], Sqrt[2], 5}
> ```

An independent Q&A on this issue: [Ordering problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2729/121)

#### Using the ordering parameter of `Sort` when `SortBy` is adequate

From a computational complexity standpoint it is far preferable to use `SortBy`, *if it can be applied* (see below), rather than the ordering parameter of `Sort`.  Using `Sort[x, p]` causes pairs of elements in `x` to be compared using `p`.  If a problem can be recast such that every element is independently given a value that can sorted by the default ordering function faster vectorized application can be used.  Taking the problem above as an example:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]  (* Mathematica 10 package *)

BenchmarkPlot[
  {Sort[#, Less] &, NumericalSort, SortBy[N]},
  Array[Sin, #] &,
  "IncludeFits" -> True
]
```

[image]

#### Working with a fixed precision can lead to unwanted results

Though faster, `SortBy[N]` can return a wrong answer for large enough inputs. One workaround is to increase the working precision by a sufficient amount. Alternatively one can use `NumericalSort` which does not have this problem.

```
exp = {π^100, π^100 - 1};

SortBy[exp, N]
SortBy[exp, N[#, 100]&]
NumericalSort[{Pi^100, Pi^100 - 1}]
```

> ```
> {π^100, π^100 - 1}
>
> {π^100 - 1, π^100}
>
> {π^100 - 1, π^100}
> ```

#### Converting to a `List` before sorting

`Sort` is capable of natively operating on all normal non-atomic expressions:

```
Sort /@ {7 -> 2, Hold[2, 1, 4], Mod[c, b, a], 1 | 4 | 1 | 5, "b"^"a"}
```

> ```
> {2 -> 7, Hold[1, 2, 4], Mod[a, b, c], 1 | 1 | 4 | 5, "a"^"b"}
> ```

Additional reading:

- [Sorting a list with secondary criterion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9840/121)
- [Sort lists according to the order of another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7679/121)
- [Sort strings by natural ordering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10619/121)
- [Unexpected result {".a", "co", ".m"} from Sort[{".m", ".a", "co"}]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26974/121)
- [Sort data after specific ordering (ascending/descending) in multiple columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2934/121)

Comment: Interestingly, if I try the benchmark plot in 10.2 I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PzQoY.png) (check the legends!).

Comment: @Sjoerd is there a material improvement or is this internal to `BenchmarkPlot`?

Comment: Can't test it right now. I'm on vacation with an old laptop with only a 10.2 trial version on it.

Comment: I get the same result as Sjoerd C. de Vries in v10.4. It's impressive to see that SortBy can do this in O(n).

Answer (score 41):

### Why is my picture upside-down?

Sometimes, when moving from data-based representations into image-based representations, odd things happen. For example, the left-most leaf in the rose

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"], "grayscale"]
```

[image]

points downwards. Yet if we extract the data in the image and plot by another means

```
imgData = ImageData[img];
ReliefPlot[imgData]
```

[image]

the left-most leaf points upwards. The image is rendered upside-down! This can be seen numerically by contrasting the dimensions of the imageData and the dimensions of the image itself:

```
ImageDimensions[img]
imgData = ImageData[img]
```

which return {223, 164} and {164, 223} respectively.

This problem is endemic to all programs that handle images/graphics and as well as data/matrices. Why? Because there are two different coordinate systems in common use. Images, like graphics, use regular Cartesian coordinates. For example, the point (1,2) means one to the right and two up. The point (10, 3) means 10 to the right and 3 up. The origin is effectively in the bottom-left and the two coordinates are indices into the (column, row).

Contrast this with matrices. Here the convention is

```
 a11 a12 a13
 a21 a22 a23
 a31 a32 a33
```

In this arrangement, the origin is effectively at the top left and the two coordinates index into the (row, column). The symptom you see (having to Reverse the ImageData) is a result of this dual-origin problem.

You can see this dual-system at work by clicking on an image. Choose "get coordinates" and the coordinate system for the image has (1,1) in the lower left. But if you choose "get indices" then the coordinate system starts in the top left. Coordinates are the image coordinates, indices index into ImageData. So for instance, ImageValue[img, {1, 1}] gives the bottom left pixel value. The documentation tries to reduce this confusion by using words like "gives the pixel value of image at position {x,y}" (for example, see the help for ImageValue) to refer to image (Cartesian) coordinates, while it uses "row," "column," and "index" when it is using matrix-indices (for example, see the help file for ImageTake).

Fortunately, there is a simple fix: to use the option `DataReversed`.

```
imgDataRev = ImageData[img, DataReversed -> True];
ReliefPlot[imgDataRev]
```

[image]

Several other plotting commands require similar processing. For example:

```
ListPlot3D[1 - imgDataRev]
```

[image]

again requires the datareversal in order to not be turned upside-down.

Two related questions with associated answers can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3747/1783) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27404/1783).

Comment: I think it's better for one to learn and live with the differences. I'm not trying to be cynical, but it seems to me that using (completely useful) `DataReversed` option can produce additional troubles with understanding.

Answer (score 41):

### Mathematica can be much more than a scratchpad

My impression is that *Mathematica* is predominately used as a super graphical calculator, or as a programming language and sometimes as a mathematical word processor. Although it is in part all of these things, there is a more powerful usage paradigm for Mathematica. *Mathematica* stackexchange itself tends to be strongly oriented towards specific programming techniques and solutions.

The more powerful and broader technique is to think of *Mathematica* as a piece of paper on which you are developing and writing your mathematical ideas, organizing them, preserving knowledge in an active form, adding textual explanation and perhaps communicating with others through *Mathematica* itself. This requires familiarity with some of the larger aspects of *Mathematica*. These suggestions are focused toward new users who are either using *Mathematica* to learn mathematical material or want to develop new and perhaps specialized material.

Most beginners use the notebook interface - but just barely. They should learn how to use `Titles`, `Sections` and `Text` cells. If I was teaching a beginner I would have the first assignment be to write a short essay without any `Input/Output` cells at all. I would have them learn how to look at the underlying expression of cells, and how to use the `ShowGroupOpener` option so a notebook could be collapsed to outline form.

Most subjects worthy of study or development require extended treatment. This means there may be multiple types of calculation or graphical or dynamic presentations. And multiple is usually simpler for a beginner with *Mathematica*. Notebooks will be more to the long than the short side.

New users should be encouraged to write their own routines when necessary. It certainly pays to make maximum use of *built-in* routines, and difficult to learn them all, but *Mathematica* is more like a meta-language from which you can construct useful routines in specific areas. Sometimes it is useful to write routines simply for convenience in usage. It's also worthwhile to think of routines as definitions, axioms, rules and specifications rather than as programs. Perhaps it is just a mindset but it is Mathematica and not C++. Routines can be put in a section at the beginning of a notebook. Again, I would teach new users how to write usage messages, `SyntaxInformation[]` statements, and define `Options[]` and `Attributes[]` for routines. Most new users would probably prefer not to be bothered with this but it represents the difference between ephemeral material and permanent active useful aquired knowledge. Writing useful routines is probably the most difficult part. Using them in longish notebooks will always expose flaws in the initial design.

A new user working on a new project should create a folder for the project in the `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` folder. This is THE place to gather material on a specific project. Then, if many useful routines have been created in the Routines sections of various notebooks, they could be moved to a package in the same Application folder. Again, it is not very difficult to write packages (especially if the routines have already been written and tested) and this makes the accumulated routines available to all notebooks.  If one gets more advanced, style sheets and palettes can be added to the same application, along with an extended folder structure.

None of the things I have discussed here (except writing actual useful routines) is especially difficult to learn. It does provide a stable framework for using Mathematica and accumulating knowledge and experience. It is the present Mathematica paradigm.

Comment: I am not certain how to make the link above so perhaps someone can help with that. I don't know how to select a specific object to link to.

Comment: Thanks, I already did it :). In the future you can get the link from under your answer (labeled **share**)

Comment: I definitely agree with this, but as a beginner I would appreciate if this post included references to some learning material. For example, a page describing the conventions for writing comments and documentation would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Newer systems have introduced a number of little functions, like `MinMax` for example, which aren't indispensable. Is this a good or bad thing? One can live with or without them, but without them there is a better chance for one being creatively active. Isn't it fun and instructive and rewarding for a novice to think about how to code the functionality of `MinMax`? These functions' existence promote instead a strange path it seems to me, where every little "math thought or procedure" will have its own method name, and learning the system will feel like learning the index.

Comment: I think you might be right, but this answer does not help  me as a beginner. After reading this I looked up  Titles and Sections in the documentation and easily learned how they work.  But I still have no idea why I would want to use them.  Maybe for my purposes they are not useful.  I write my mathematics up in LaTeX, often for publication, and Mathematica is not going to replace that.  What advantage would i get from using titles and sections?

Answer (score 27):

### Why do I get an empty plot?

Often new *Mathematica* users (and some not-so-new users) post questions asking why their plot of some expression just shows axes, with no plotted curve appearing. The key thing to keep in mind is that *this will almost never have to do with the `Plot` command itself*. It invariably occurs because the expression is not evaluating to a real numeric value when supplied a numeric value for the plot variable. The troubleshooting step is to evaluate the expression outside of the `Plot` statement, so that you can see what it's actually producing. This is necessary because `Plot` will not complain when given non-numeric values to plot -- it just won't plot.

For example, new users will sometimes do

```
y = sin[x] + cos[x]
Plot[y, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

and then wonder why the plot is empty. The first check is to supply a numeric argument for `x` and apply `N`:

```
y /. x -> Pi // N
```

> `cos[3.14159] + sin[3.14159]`

If you don't get a numerical result, that is why the plot is empty. (The next step would be to look up `sin` and `cos` and find the correct spellings.)

A second common situation is if the expression is numeric but complex, such as in [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44489/8253) [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85538/8253). Again, evaluate the expression outside the plot to see that there is an imaginary part, and then apply `Re` or `Chop` as appropriate to obtain the plot.

In other cases, the problem may be due to an incorrectly defined function, such as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4102/8253):

```
a = (b + c)/d;
plotFunction[b_, c_] := Plot[a, {d, 0, 10}];
plotFunction[2, 3]
```

Define the function without the plot statement to see the problem:

```
plotFunction[b_, c_] := a /. d -> 5 // N;
plotFunction[2, 3]
```

> `0.2 (b + c)`

The result is not numeric because the patterns (`b_` and `c_`) don't correspond to the global variables `b` and `c` and so the arguments are not substituted.

There are some cases in which the attributes of `Plot` are important to the problem -- for example in [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4347/8253) [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27680/8253) the empty plot is a consequence of the `HoldAll` attribute of `Plot`.

Comment: It is strange that `Plot` silently fails while e.g. `NIntegrate` gives a helpful error message: `y = sin[x] + cos[x]; NIntegrate[y, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]` `NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand cos[x]+sin[x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,6.28319}}. >>`. Is there any sound reason for that omission or should this really be a feature?

Comment: @masterxilo There used to be such an error message in Mathematica -- it was removed in version 6. And it looks like Szabolcs [complained about that](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Sep/msg00230.html) then. Maybe the thinking was that a graphics command does not need to provide a mathematically rigorous result, so it should just do the best it can and not bother you with error messages. That makes it less annoying when plotting a function that is only real over a restricted range, but I agree that a message might be helpful when the function is nonnumerical everywhere.

Comment: @masterxilo At one point the message could be turned back on with `On[General::plnr]`, but that doesn't seem to work any more.

Answer (score 24):

### Misunderstanding `Dynamic`

Although this FAQ is to "focus on non-advanced uses" and [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) functionality is arguably advanced it *seems* simple and is one of the more important pitfalls of which I am aware.  I have observed two primary misunderstandings which may be countered in two statements:

1. It does not provide continuous independent evaluation; it works only when "visible."
2. It remains part of an expression though it is not usually displayed; it is not magic.

`Dynamic` is fundamentally a Front End construct, though the Front End communicates with the Kernel over special channels for its evaluation.  It is typically only active while it is within the visible area of a *Mathematica* window. (e.g. Notebook or Palette.)  To demonstrate this simply create a Notebook with enough lines to scroll completely off screen and evaluate:

```
Dynamic[Print @ SessionTime[]; SessionTime[], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

This creates an expression which appears as a number that changes roughly once a second, and as a side effect it also prints to the Messages window.  One may observe that when the expression is scrolled out of the visible area of the Notebook or the Notebook is minimized the printing ceases.  I put "visible" in quotes because it is not really the visibility of the expression that is key. For example if the Notebook is behind another window it still updates and if the expression is outside the visible area it may still update while the Notebook is being edited, etc.

The point is that `Dynamic` does not spawn an independent parallel process but rather it is a Front End formatting construct with special properties.  Realizing this will help one to understand why something like this doesn't work as presumably intended:

```
If[
  Dynamic[SessionTime[], UpdateInterval -> 1] > 10,
  Print["Ten second session"]
]
```

You get an output expression that appears like this:

> ```
> If[19.9507407 > 10, Print[Ten second session]]
> ```

This cannot work however because:

1. You are comparing a numeric expression `10` to one with the head `Dynamic`.
2. In this output `If` it not an active construct and it cannot print anything.

The formatted expression displayed by the Front End is actually:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 DynamicBox[ToBoxes[
   If[SessionTime[] > 10, 
    Print["Ten second session"]], StandardForm],
  ImageSizeCache->{48., {0., 13.}},
  UpdateInterval->1]], "Output"]
```

`Dynamic` does nothing but result in this formatted output which is specially handled by the Front End.

It is possible to make the example work at least superficially by wrapping the entire `If` expression in `Dynamic` instead but it is important to understand that this does not avoid the fundamental limitations of the construct, it merely defers them.  For example instead of evaluating and printing *once*, which is what I think people usually intend when they write something like this, `If` evaluates (and prints) repeatedly with every update.

Although it can be disappointing to realize that `Dynamic` is not as "magical" as it may first appear it is still a very powerful tool and works over channels that are not otherwise directly accessible to the user.  It needs to be understood before it is applied indiscriminately and other functionality should also be known, for example:

- [Background and Scheduled Tasks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BackgroundAndScheduledTasks.html)
- [Concurrency](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Concurrency.html)

---

A concise and more authoritative post about `Dynamic` by John Fultz that opened my eyes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581155

Comment: Nice answer, I think you identified some nice common mistakes. Re: "Dynamic is fundamentally a Front End construct", I just wanted to rant here. We have that `MakeBoxes[Dynamic[x]]` evaluates to `DynamicBox[ToBoxes[x,StandardForm]]`. It is then the `DynamicBox` that is a "Front End construct", that is probably tracked by the Front End in a special way. At this point we can imagine that no expression with head `Dynamic` needs to be handled anymore, we are just evaluating an expression with head `ToBoxes` when the Front End asks for it.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks.  I am trying to keep this answer approachable for new users while not being inaccurate.  (And I admit that I may not correctly understand all this myself.)  I did write "The formatted expression displayed by the Front End is actually:" and show `DynamicBox[ToBoxes[ . . .` and then "`Dynamic` does nothing but result in this formatted output which is specially handled by the Front End."  That is how I chose to describe what I think you are commenting on above.  Do you think you can improve it without making this answer too advanced?

Comment: I am sorry I must say I had a follow up comment before, in which I also said everything was probably fine. I deleted that comment because I confused myself. Most likely I had some lingering `DynamicBox`es evaluating expressions when I didn't expect them to get evaluated. If you can still see that comment, it was probably correct :). I really like your statements in quotes in your comment, which do a good job of providing more details. It also makes sense to make a global (possibly slightly ambiguous) statement first and provide details later on.

Comment: I'm a bit rushed and probably still confused writing this, so I should probably not edit, as I would probably only cause more confusion :). Thanks for the reply, it is a kind thing to reply to a rushed comment or rant :).

Comment: Can one look on a dynamic output as an object, object-subscriber, that listens to events? The dynamic cell has and deals with some variables, and events in which those variables change (outside or inside the cell) are the events the cell listens to? And upon the events, displaying actions are triggered?

Comment: @BoLe If I understand you I think one can look at it that way, but *critically* it only listens or triggers when its `DynamicBox` expression is visible in the Front End.

Answer (score 24):

### Use `Rasterize[..., "Image"]` to avoid double rasterization

[**UPDATE**: starting from version 11.2.0 `Rasterize[...]` defaults to `Rasterize[..., "Image"]`.]

When working with image processing functions like `ImageDimensions`, `ImageResize` etc. it is important to know that these functions always expect an object with `Head` `Image` as input and not `Graphics`. It is somewhat counterintuitive but `Rasterize` by default produces not an `Image` but a `Graphics` object which will be tacitly rasterized **again** with potential loss of quality when one feeds it as input for any `Image`-processing function. To avoid this one should ensure to set the second argument of `Rasterize` to `"Image"`.

Here is an illustration (I upsample with no interpolation to make the difference more evident):

```
gr = Rasterize[x^2 + y^2, ImageSize -> 100, RasterSize -> 300]
i = Rasterize[x^2 + y^2, "Image", ImageSize -> 100, RasterSize -> 300]

ImageResize[gr, Scaled[3], Resampling -> "Constant"]
ImageDimensions@%
ImageResize[i, Scaled[3], Resampling -> "Constant"]
ImageDimensions@%
```

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Detailed explanations

For elucidating what happens here, it is handy to use my [shortInputForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function:

```
gr // shortInputForm
```

[image: screenshot]

From the output it is seen that `gr` is a `Graphics` object with option `ImageSize -> 100` containing a `Raster` with 300 columns of pixels. These are due to the options `ImageSize -> 100, RasterSize -> 300` passed to `Rasterize`. We can also get the dimensions of the `Raster` array in the following way:

```
gr[[1, 1]] // Dimensions
```

> ```
> {104, 300, 3}
> ```

(the first number is the number of rows, the second is the number of columns and the third is the length of the RGB triplets in the array).

One should understand that `Graphics` is by definition a container for *vector* graphics (but can contain as well raster objects represented via `Raster`). And hence there is no general way to convert `Graphics` into `Image` (a container for purely raster graphics) other than rasterization.

Since `gr` has option `ImageSize -> 100`, after re-rasterization the final `Image` will contain 100 columns of pixels:

```
Image[gr] // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {100, 35}
> ```

Hence **we have irreversibly resized** the original raster image contained in `gr` from 300 pixels wide to 100 pixels wide! This automatically happens when we pass `gr` to `ImageResize` because the algorithms of the latter are for **the rasters only** and hence can work only with `Image`, not with `Graphics`. Actually the same is true for any `Image*` function, not just `ImageResize`. For example, `gr // ImageDimensions` will produce the same as `Image[gr] // ImageDimensions`  since `Image` is tacitly applied when you apply any `Image*` function to a non-`Image`:

```
gr // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {100, 35}
> ```

The fact of the second rasterization can be directly proven by tracing the evaluation with `Trace`:

```
trace = Trace[ImageDimensions[gr], Image, TraceInternal -> True, TraceDepth -> 2]
```

[image: screenshot]

Let us investigate the output:

```
trace[[1, 1]] // shortInputForm
trace[[1, 2, 1]] // Head
```

[image: screenshot]

So we see that `Image` is applied to `gr` directly and as the result an object with `Head` `Image` is returned.

To produce the final result `ImageResize` resizes the intermediate `Image` 3 times as requested by the second argument (`Scaled[3]`), and produces an `Image` with dimensions

```
{100, 35}*3
```

> ```
> {300, 105}
> ```

For the case of `i` the intermediate rasterization does not happen and hence we get the final image with dimensions

```
ImageDimensions[i]*3
```

> ```
> {900, 312}
> ```

This is because `i` is already an `Image`:

```
Head[i]
```

> ```
> Image
> ```

---

#### Final remarks

It is worth to note that `Raster` can be converted into `Image` directly without loss of quality:

```
rasterArray = gr[[1, 1]];
i2 = Image[Reverse[rasterArray], "Byte"];
i2 // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {300, 104}
> ```

Another method is to apply `Image` directly to `Raster` container:

```
i3 = Image[gr[[1]]];
i3 // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {300, 104}
> ```

Opposite conversion is also straightforward:

```
Reverse[ImageData[i2, Automatic]] == rasterArray == Reverse[ImageData[i3, Automatic]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

The obtained images are essentially equivalent to the one obtained with `"Image"` as the second argument of `Rasterize`:

```
ImageData[i3, Automatic] == ImageData[i2, Automatic] == ImageData[i, Automatic]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

The only difference is in options:

```
Options /@ {i, i2, i3}

{{ColorSpace -> "RGB", ImageSize -> 100, Interleaving -> True}, 
 {ColorSpace -> Automatic, Interleaving -> True}, 
 {ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True}}
```

Comment: Can you comment on why the two `ImageResize` results have different sizes? In what way (with what resolution) is `gr` "rasterized again" when passed to `ImageResize`?

Comment: @masterxilo I have added detailed explanations.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov would you expect to need explicit `PageWidth -> 500, 
  LineBreakWithin -> Automatic` inside a cell in `Rasterize[
 Cell[boxdata, "Code", PageWidth -> 500, 
  LineBreakWithin -> Automatic], ImageFormattingWidth -> 500]` to make `ImageFormattingWidht` working?

Comment: @Kuba Certainly not. Moreover, checking the Documentation examples for `ImageFormattingWidth` and `$ImageFormattingWidth` shows that this functionality is currently broken. Worth to report.

Answer (score 21):

## Fourier transforms do not return the expected result

Many users know a particular definition of the Fourier transform. When *Mathematica* returns an unexpected result and users cannot comprehend what is happening, often it is because *Mathematica* is using a different definition. In particular, this is the general definition of a transform pair:

$$
F(\omega) = \sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2\pi)^{1-a}}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{i b \omega t} \mathrm{d}t,\quad 
f(t) = \sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2\pi)^{1+a}}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i b \omega t} \mathrm{d}t
$$

Clearly there is not just one definition of the Fourier transform, but an infinite number of definitions. Some common choices are:

- $(a,b) = (0,1)$ (default in *Mathematica*)
- $(a,b) = (-1,1)$
- $(a,b) = (1,-1)$

$(a,b)$ can be set through the option `FourierParameters -> {a,b}` in Fourier related functions, e.g. `Fourier`, `FourierSeries` and `FourierTransform`.

Three common usage scenarios are presented below.

#### Make a Fourier transform agree with its table expression

If you are reading a math book on Fourier analysis it might say that
$$
\mathcal{F}(e^{-at^2})=\frac{\pi}{a}e^{-\omega^2/4a},
$$
but this is not what *Mathematica* returns by default. By looking at how the book defines the Fourier transform you realize that you need to use `FourierParameters -> {1,-1}`.

**Related questions:**

- [Why does InverseFourierTransform gives different result to doing it by hand?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82703/731)

#### Change the periodicity of a Fourier series

A close inspection of the expression above shows that the parameter $b$ affects the periodicity of the Fourier transform. Below is a demonstration of how to approximate a $4\pi$ periodic sine curve with a Fourier series. The leftmost figure shows the sine curve, the middle figure shows the Fourier series without changing `FourierParameters` and the right figure shows the sine series after changing `FourierParameters`.

```
pl1 = Plot[Sin[0.5 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}];

fs[t_] = FourierTrigSeries[Sin[0.5 t], t, 10];
pl2 = Plot[fs[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}];

fs2[t_] = FourierTrigSeries[Sin[0.5 t], t, 10, FourierParameters -> {0, 0.5}];
pl3 = Plot[fs2[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}];

GraphicsRow[{pl1, pl2, pl3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since the curve is $4\pi$ periodic, $b = \frac{2\pi}{4 \pi} = 0.5$. When $b=1$ as it is by default the signal is assumed to be $2\pi$ periodic, which causes our $4\pi$ periodic curve to be truncated. The middle figure shows the segment $(-\pi,\pi)$ starting over at $\pi$ because of this.

**Related questions**

- [Changing Function Domain of Fourier Series](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76493/731)
- [FourierSeries command, for arbitrary period T?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115504/731)
- [Fourier series for rectangular wave incorrect, why?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50918/731)

#### Affecting the FFT

`FourierParameters` also affects the discrete Fourier transform. In fact, the discrete Fourier transform of a list $\mu_r$ with length $n$ is given in *Mathematica* by
$$
F(s) = \frac{1}{n^{(1-a)/2}}\sum_{r=1}^n\mu_re^{2\pi i b(r-1)(s-1)/n},\ s\in\{1, ..., n\}.
$$
Confusion over the Fourier spectrum can arise when switching from *MATLAB* – or another software – to *Mathematica* for example since *MATLAB* uses a different set of Fourier parameters. Below is an example that shows how the amplitude of the FFT is affected by *Mathematica*'s choice of parameters and *MATLAB*'s choice of parameters, respectively.

```
data = Table[10 Cos[4 t], {t, -Pi, Pi, 0.1}];

ft1 = Fourier[data];
pl2 = ListPlot[Abs[ft1], PlotRange -> Full];

ft2 = Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
pl3 = ListPlot[Abs[ft2], PlotRange -> Full];

GraphicsRow[{pl2, pl3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Related questions**

- [How can I obtain a zero-filled Fourier transform, as produced by MATLAB's fft?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17168/how-can-i-obtain-a-zero-filled-fourier-transform-as-produced-by-matlabs-fft/17169#17169)
- [Fourier transform in *Mathematica* is different from Octave](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127323/fourier-in-mathematica-different-from-octave)

Answer (score 16):

### How to use both initialized and uninitialized variables

A variable in Mathematica can play two different roles. As an initialized variable, the variable's value will replace its name when an expression is evaluated. By contrast, upon evaluation, the name of an uninitialized variable will be propagated throughout every expression in which it takes part.

For example, starting with the more familiar behavior of an initialized variable in Mathematica, as in most programming languages, we have

> a = 5.3;
>
> (5 a)^2
>
> ===> 702.25

But if the variable a becomes uninitialized again, as by the use of Clear, we see the following result from the identical input expression:

> Clear[a];
>
> (5 a)^2
>
> ===> 25 a^2

This behavior makes perfectly good mathematical sense, but it is very different from that of most other programming languages, and can indeed be quite confusing to a newcomer. Mathematica can even seem to be perverse or crazy when this distinction has not been understood.

But propagating the names of variables through mathematical operations is a great feature when you want to perform algebraic manipulation. For example, assuming a, b and c are all uninitialized,

Expand[ (a + 2 b + 3 c)^2 ]

> ===> a^2 + 4 a b + 4 b^2 + 6 a c + 12 b c + 9 c^2

As a particularly important case, variables whose values are to be found by Solve (and similar functions such as Reduce and FindInstance) MUST be uninitialized.

Fortunately in Mathematica's front end the color of an initialized variable is different from the color of an uninitialized variable. Check your system to see what colors are in use. Getting into the habit of noticing the colors of variables will also make clear how Mathematica keeps certain variables local to their contexts.

Comment: Using scoping constructs like `Block[ ]` or formal symbols like `\[FormalX]` is more robust than looking at the syntax coloring, I believe

Comment: I'm sure you are right. My answer is only about understanding what is going on with the language. New users often type in things which don't work, and then get more confused when Mathematica returns answers that they find incomprehensible.

Answer (score 15):

### Understand the difference between `Set` (or `=`) and `Equal` (or `==`)

Suppose you want to solve the system of equations $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x = 2y$ in Mathematica.  So you type in the following code:

```
Solve[{x^2 + y^2 = 1, x = 2 y}, {x, y}]
```

You then get the following output:

> Set::write: Tag Plus in x^2+y^2 is Protected. >>
>
> Solve::ivar: 2 y is not a valid variable. >>
>
> `Solve[{1, 2 y}, {2 y, y}]`

What's going on?

The answer is that unlike some other programming languages, Mathematica has separate commands for setting a variable to a given value (`Set`, denoted by a single equals sign) and checking to see whether two variables are equal (`Equal`, denoted by a double equals sign.)  To illustrate the difference, consider the following two pieces of code:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
a = b
(*
==> 2
*)
```

versus

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
a == b
(*
==> False
*)
```

In both sets of code, we first set `a` equal to 1 and `b` equal to 2.  In the first code, we then set `a` equal to `b`;  this means that `a` is now equal to 2 in memory, and any further commands that refer to `a` will return `2`.  In the second one, however, we ask Mathematica whether `a` is equal to `b`;  it returns `False`, since 1 is not equal to 2.  However, Mathematica has not overwritten the value for `a` (or `b`) stored in memory;  any further commands that refer to `a` will assume that `a` is equal to 1.

For this reason, when you call one of Mathematica's many equation-solving commands (e.g., `Solve`, `NSolve`, `DSolve`, `NDSolve`, and `FindRoot`), you need to provide the equations using `Equal` rather than `Set`:

```
Solve[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x == 2 y}, {x, y}]
(*
==> {{x -> -(2/Sqrt[5]), y -> -(1/Sqrt[5])}, {x -> 2/Sqrt[5],  y -> 1/Sqrt[5]}}
*)
```

In the first code that I typed out above, the following series of events happened:

- Mathematica came to the first entry in the first list.  It interpreted it as "take the expression `x^2 + y^2` and set it equal to 1."  Since the "head" of this expression is `Plus`, this was effectively an attempt to overwrite the notion of addition in Mathematica (at least for these two expressions), and so Mathematica returned the first error.
- Mathematica came to the second entry in the first list.  It interpreted it as "take the expression `x` and set it equal to `2y`".  It dutifully did so, without complaint.
- Mathematica attempted to solve the equations.  However, since we had already set `x` equal to `2y` above, it thought that we were trying to solve a system of  equations for `2y` and `y` simultaneously.  Hence, it generated the second error message.

---

Finally:  if you make this error and then correct it, **you must clear the old variable definitions before your code will work!**  Otherwise, those definitions that you accidentally made will still be in memory, and you'll get a result like

```
Solve[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x == 2 y}, {x, y}]
(*
==> Solve[{5 y^2 == 1, True}, {2 y, y}]
*)
```

The `True` above is Mathematica basically saying "well, you already told me to set `x` equal to `2y`, so when I check whether `x` is equal to `2y`, it's true."  Usually, the quickest and easiest way to fix things if you make this mistake is to quit the kernel;  this clears all the lingering erroneous definitions away, and gives you a clean slate to work on.

Comment: Instead of quitting kernel, clearing global space may be better. Also, if one uses formal variable symbols that are protected, like `\[FormalX]` (or, typing _escape $x escape_), one cannot assign them values, they can only be compared.

Comment: Perhaps you should bring together the miscellaneous discussions of SameQ under this topic as well?

Comment: If you're going to present the difference between `=` and `==`, why not immediately include `===` (`SameQ`)? I see people using `==` when you really should be using `===` quite regularly. It's quite an insidious mistake because it will work for a while and then your code suddenly screws up when you least expect it.

Comment: How about including `:=` in this article?

Answer (score 13):

### `Association`/`<||>` objects are Atomic and thus unmatchable before 10.4

`AtomQ@Association[]` yields `True`.

This is confusing because it is not stated anywhere in the manual. For example [tutorial/BasicObjects#15871](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicObjects.html#15871) claims that only numbers (including complex ones), Strings and Symbols are atomic objects. [guide/AtomicElementsOfExpressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AtomicElementsOfExpressions.html) does not mention `Association` either, neither does [guide/Associations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html).

`Association@@{a -> b, c -> d}` does not act like `association @@ {a -> b, c -> d}`, although the `FullForm` suggests it does

```
association @@ {a -> b, c -> d} // FullForm
Association @@ {a -> b, c -> d} // FullForm
```

The `Association[]` constructor function does a non trivial job, such that the following are both `False`:

```
MatchQ[Association[], Unevaluated@Association[]]
MatchQ[Unevaluated@Association[], Association[]]
```

Also, `MatchQ[<|x->1|>, Association[___]] === False`. **Note:** `MatchQ[<|x->1|>, Association[___]]` should evaluate to `True` (checked with version 11.1)

> standard pattern matching inside the structure will not work.

You are probably best off converting associations to rule lists before pattern matching via `Normal`: `MatchQ[Normal@<|x -> 1|>, {___}] === True`.

#### Statement from WRI

> It just so happens that Association is currently AtomQ, though I've
>   argued strongly against that fact internally, and I've got SW's say-so
>   that we'll change that eventually. But that doesn't have all that much
>   to do with pattern matching not working inside associations: we all
>   agree it should, it's just hard to do efficiently and we couldn't
>   deliver it for 10. So, to sum up: Association will not be AtomQ
>   forever, and it will support pattern matching eventually. There's a
>   correlation here, not a causation.

#### Further reading

[How to match Association[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113020/how-to-match-association)

[MatchQ-ing Associations (MMA 10)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55526/matchq-ing-associations-mma-10)

#### Fixed in 10.4

> In Mathematica 10.4, `Association` can now be used in pattern matching.
>
> There's now also `KeyValuePattern` which is a pattern object
>   specifically to match elements of an Association or list of rules.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109383/6804

Answer (score 13):

### How to work always in [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) mode?

#### How to get in PDF format exactly what I see in my Notebook?

It is counterintuitive and undocumented, but *Mathematica* by default prints to PostScript printers and also exports in PDF and EPS formats using a set of style definitions which differs from the one used for displaying Notebooks on screen. Hence **you often unexpectedly get your graphics in PDF/EPS damaged**: font sizes and magnification of different elements may differ significantly from what you carefully tuned during your interactive work with Notebook. The reason is that FrontEnd uses for on-screen display a set of styles determined by `ScreenStyleEvironment` option, but for printing (exporting to PostScript) the styles are determined by `PrintingStyleEnvironment` option:

```
Options[$DefaultFrontEnd, {ScreenStyleEnvironment, PrintingStyleEnvironment}]
```

> ```
> {PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout", ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"}
> ```

(Note that for the all other formats `Export` uses `ScreenStyleEnvironment`, exporting to PostScript is the only exception.) So for turning on the [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) mode you should set the value of the global `$FrontEnd` option `PrintingStyleEnvironment` identical to the value of the `ScreenStyleEnvironment` option:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

Note also that `Export` ignores the value of this option set on the `Notebook[]` level and always uses the global (`$FrontEnd`) setting!

---

#### Further details

Apart from `ScreenStyleEnvironment` the on-screen display is also influenced by such options as `StyleDefinitions`, `Magnification`, `GraphicsBoxOptions` and `StyleHints` (starting from version 10). From them `Magnification` and `GraphicsBoxOptions` affect only on-screen display and do not affect `Export`, while `StyleHints` affects both on-screen display and `Export`.

For vector formats `Export` ignores `StyleDefinitions` set on the Notebook level and uses global `DefaultStyleDefinitions` setting instead. More information can be found in

- [Default styles for Exporting to PDF, EPS and SVG](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139948/280)

For raster formats `Export` uses local `StyleDefinitions`. Some additional information can be found in

- [Rasterize uses default stylesheet if ImageSize is specified](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36689/280)

---

**Related (publication quality export, using *Mathematica* as desktop publishing tool):**

- [Bug in Export of figures with PlotMarkers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/249973/280)
- [Export a graph to pdf but size does not match](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/251122/280)
- [PDF export has inaccurate dimensions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261937/280)
- [Tutorial on creating publication quality documents in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136426/280)

Answer (score 12):

#### Omitting ; can cause unexpected results in functions

A missing ; somewhere inside a function is my number one reason for time-consuming debugging because there are no error messages indicating that something is wrong and where the error is. Here a simple example:

Assume you write a function that performs some iterative calculation in a `While` loop and once some condition is fulfilled it returns the result (in the example just the input variable). To see the progress of your function you print the iteration counter at every iteration, but forget to put a semicolon at the end of the print command.

```
f1[x_] := 
  Block[{counter},
    counter = 0;
    While[counter < 5,
      counter += 1;
      Print[counter]
      (* Note the missing ; after the Print[] command. 
         This will not throw an error. *)
      If[counter > 2, Return[x]];];];
```

Now you execute `f1[20]`. It prints

> `f1[20]`
>
> `1`
>
> `2`
>
> `3`
>
> `4`
>
> `5`

and generates no output. It seems that the `Return[x]` part of the code did not work. However, the `If` experesion works just fine, as can be seen when putting some debug print message just there:

```
f2[x_] := 
  Block[{counter},
    counter = 0;
    While[counter < 5,
      counter += 1;
      Print[counter]
      (* Note the missing ; after the Print[] command. 
         This will not throw an error. *)
      If[counter > 2, Print["if has been successfully evaluated"]; 
      Return[x]];];];
```

With the result

> `f2[20]`
>
> `1`
>
> `2`
>
> `3`
>
> `if has been successfully evaluated`
>
> `4`
>
> `if has been successfully evaluated`
>
> `5`
>
> `if has been successfully evaluated`

The problem is that `Return` behaves differently if there is no ; after the `Print` command somewhere up in the chain. In fact, due to the missing ; the `Return` only returns from the not properly bundled statement `Print[counter]If[...]` (remember that newlines are just decorations) and not from the actual function. Fixing the issue solves the problem:

```
f3[x_] := 
  Block[{counter},
    counter = 0;
    While[counter < 5,
      counter += 1;
      Print[counter];
      If[counter > 2, Print["if has been successfull evaluated"]; 
      Return[x]];];];
```

> `f3[20]`
>
> `1`
>
> `2`
>
> `3`
>
> `if has been successfully evaluated`
>
> `20`

It is possible to see the change by the different indent of what comes after the `Print`.

Note: this answer was written by Felix (user:38410) as an update to another answer, but I have made it a stand-alone answer because it really deals with a different pitfall than the other answer. [m_goldberg]

Comment: `Trace` seems to indicate that omitting the semicolon  in Print["msg"]If[True,1,0] is interpreted as an implied a `Times` expression, so it still parses without error.

Comment: Related: [Is there a guideline about when to end expressions with semicolons?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41086/121)

Answer (score 10):

## In symbolic algebra, `x[1]` is quite different from `x1`. This one-liner avoids problems and gets nice subscript formatting.

```
x[i_Integer] := x[i] = 
   With[
     {u = Unique[x]}, 
     Format[u] = Subscript[x,i];
     u
   ]
```

There are many advantages to using `x[1]`, `x[2]`, ... as symbolic variables, such as creating a list of them with `Array[x, 5]` to pass into `Solve[]`, or creating a list of expressions with `Table[x[i] + x[i + 1], {i, 5}]`.

There are also some good reasons to avoid this practice. Some operations choke on them. Writing `x[1]` sometimes declares that `x` is a function of one variable only and `x[1]` may be assumed constant.

They also are not formatted as subscripts. Using `Subscript[x,1]` as a variable also invites trouble. The above one-liner solves both problems.

`Array[x, 4]` then displays as $\left\{\text{x}_1,\text{x}_2,\text{x}_3,\text{x}_4\right\}$, actually (say) `{x$2136, x$2152, x$2163, x$2164}`.

`Table[x[i] + x[i + 1], {i, 3}]` returns $\{\text{x}_1 + \text{x}_2, \text{x}_2 + \text{x}_3, \text{x}_3 + \text{x}_4\}$.

Further reading:

- [What are the requirements for a well behaved indexed variable? Subscript, ToExpression, Downvalue?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/280)
- [Basic syntax issue, point 3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/27951)

Comment: ??x does not show the internal form.  `DownValues[x]//InputForm `does, but does not list the `Format` definitions.  How can I make `Information["x"]` print the internal values?  How can I discover what `Format` definitions exist?

Comment: I made a new answer because this one is very different from what 3 people downvoted.  I hope it will be judged on its merits.

Comment: `FullDefinition[x]` should show what you want.

Comment: It seems `FormatValues[]` contains the definitions.  It's hard to print it, though, because the `Format` gets applied even to things inside `HoldComplete[]`. `FormatType` inside the `MakeBoxes` rule triggers an error message. `With[{XX=x[100]}, With[{fvxx=FormatValues[XX]}, FormatValues[XX]={}; Print[fvxx/.{Format->"Format",Subscript->"Subscript"}];FormatValues[XX]=fvxx ]];`
 prints `{HoldPattern[Format[x$145]] :> Subscript[x, 100],
     HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[x$145, FormatType_]] :> Format[Subscript[x, 100], FormatType]}`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I finally understand what you're talking about.  Consider `FullDefinition[x] // InputForm`

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222418/7288 on how to automatically create symbols with names like `x₁` (which is a single identifier with a Unicode subscript character).

Answer (score 7):

### Plot functions do not print output (Where are my plots?)

Quite often new users write something like this and are surprised that no plots are produced:

```
For[
  n = 1,
  n <= 3,
  n++,
  Plot[Sin[x*n], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
]
```

Since version 6 of *Mathematica* the plot functions ([`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html), [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html), [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html), [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html), etc.) do not print their output but instead evaluate to a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) or [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) expression, just as `2 + 2` evaluates to `4`.

To see the output of `Plot` in this loop one needs to write it to the Notebook as a side-effect which is exactly what [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) does.  This can be done explicitly (`Print[ Plot[. . .] ]`) or by setting [`$DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$DisplayFunction.html) to something with a side-effect [as it was in versions 5.2 and earlier.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47113/why-is-this-semicolon-in-red/47123#47123)

A better approach is to collect and display the direct output of `Plot` as it may be manipulated like any other expression.  The most direct substitute for the `For` loop is [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html):

```
Table[
  Plot[Sin[x*n], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
  {n, 1, 3}
]
```

[image]

This returns (evaluates to) a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) containing three `Graphics` expressions.  These expressions are displayed by the [Front End](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NotebookInterfaceOverview.html) as graphical objects that may be [interactively manipulated](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EditingWolframLanguageGraphicsOverview.html).  This output may be [assigned](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Assignments.html) to a [Symbol](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningVariables.html) or [Indexed Object](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html).  It may be displayed in particular arrangements using e.g. [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html), [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html), [`Multicolumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multicolumn.html), [`GraphicsRow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsRow.html), etc., or animated with [`ListAnimate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html)

The `Graphics` expressions may be modified with the full range of [expression manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Expressions.html) tools, sometimes referred to as [*post-processing*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=[plotting]%20%22post-processing%22) as one starts with the existing plot output.

Answer (score 7):

### `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` can yield irreproducible results.

For example, the procedure `doPlot` below

1. computes a `SmoothKernelDistribution` on a *fixed* data vector (`DATA`);
2. defines a `pdf` function based on this distribution;
3. plots the `pdf` function.

```
doPlot[] := Module[{
    pdf,
    distribution = SmoothKernelDistribution[DATA,
                                            "StandardGaussian", "Biweight", 
                                            PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
   },
   pdf = Function[x, PDF[distribution, x]];
   Plot[pdf[x], {x, 0, 180000}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.00004}},
        Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None,
        ImageSize -> 50, AspectRatio -> 1, ImagePadding -> {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]
]
```

Since `doPlot` takes no arguments, one could hope that it would produce the same results every time, but this is not the case.  The figure below shows the result of 100 runs of `doPlot`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It appears that "reproducibility" is one of the ingredients of "Quality" that one forfeits when one specifies `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`.  This is not outlandish, of course, but it is not self-evident either.

Answer (score 6):

**`Assocation` component access `[]` vs `[[]]`**

With MMA we spend a lot of time manipulating lists where access to components is done by `[[index]]`, this can make us forget that when using `Association` keys, the syntax is `[key]`.

If keys are integers this can be a source a bug:

```
a = <|0 -> "A", 1 -> "B", 2 -> "C", 3 -> "D"|>

a[[2]]

Out: = "B"

a[2]

Out: "C"
```

If you want to use `Part` to access associations with arbitrary keys, you need the wrapper `Key`:

```
a[[Key[2]]]

Out[]= "C"
```

This can be used to access multiple keys as well:

```
a[[{Key[2], Key[3]}]]    

Out[]= <|2 -> "C", 3 -> "D"|>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Understanding `$Context`, `$ContextPath` the parsing stage and runtime scoping constructs

A *symbol* in Mathematica can never be without a *context*. We can assume that the internal representation of any symbol stores a string of the form `` "context`symbol" ``.

But for you as a programmer, there are ways to enter a symbol without stating it's full context: `x`, `Sin`,  `` `x `` are all valid inputs.

The values of `$Context` and `$ContextPath` at the parsing stage determine which symbol is actually meant by the above inputs.

This settles which symbols are initially used in the expression put together that will be submitted to the evaluator. You can display the *actual* name of symbols in a snippet of code by printing the "`FullForm`" of an expression *with* context as follows:

```
Hold[

(*your code here*)
x

] /. x_Symbol :> Context@x <> SymbolName@Unevaluated@x
(*=>*)
"System`Hold"["Global`x"]
```

(see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119922/fullform-with-context-for-each-symbol) for more ways of doing this). Note that Mathematica strips the context whenever possible, even in FullForm, to present to you more or less what you (supposedly) entered: `` Global`y `` is displayed as just `y`.

However, at runtime, an `x` that is parsed as `` Global`x `` might well become something else still. Let's try the following:

```
Hold[
  
  Module[{x}, x]
  
  ] /. x_Symbol :> Context@x <> SymbolName@Unevaluated@x
```

gives

```
"System`Hold"["System`Module"["System`List"["Global`x"], "Global`x"]]
```

So the variable is *parsed* as `` Global`x ``. But *evaluating* `Module[{x}, x]` we get something like `x$11686`. `Module` changed every literal occurrence of `` Global`x `` to a variable created probably via `Unique@Unevaluated@x` before executing the code.

However, this replacement is aware of some *scoping constructs* of the language which it will not enter. `Rule` is one of them:

```
Module[{x}, {x, x_ -> x}]
```

gives

```
{x$12264, x_ -> x}
```

And not say `{x$12264, x$12264_ -> x$12264}`.

`With` and `Function` are also scoping constructs which interact. Here for example, every `x` is *parsed* as `` Global`x ``:

```
Hold[
  
  With[{y = x}, Function[{x}, x + y]]
  
  ] /. x_Symbol :> Context@x <> SymbolName@Unevaluated@x
(*=>*)
System`Hold[System`With[System`List[System`Set[Global`y,Global`x]],System`Function[System`List[Global`x],System`Plus[Global`x,Global`y]]]]
```

But in the result of evaluation a new symbol `x$` will have been created to resolve a (potential) name clash:

```
Function[{x$}, x$ + x]
```

---

`BeginPackage`, `Begin` and messages like

`*::shdw: Symbol * appears in multiple contexts {*}; definitions in context * may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>`

also fall into this complex of considerations.

#### Related questions and "articles"

Many questions tagged with `variable-definitions` `scoping` and `contexts` deal with this topic. Here's a selection:

[Context of localised (dynamic) symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75333/6804)

[DynamicModule Initialization is not executing when expected?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97966/dynamicmodule-initialization-is-not-executing-when-expected?lq=1)

[How to scope `Pattern` labels in rules/set?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119876/how-to-scope-pattern-labels-in-rules-set)

[How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/how-to-make-a-function-like-set-but-with-a-block-construct-for-the-pattern-name)

[tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html)

[package import problem in mathematica (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664091/package-import-problem-in-mathematica)

Comment: Is this really a "common pitfall awaiting new users?"  It's tricky admittedly, but hardly a pitfall until you start writing packages, imo.

Comment: Even when you want to *use packages* (which is basic/should be encouraged) you need to know that you cannot put ``(Needs["Apackage`"]; PackageFunction[...];)`` into one expression (or one *line* in the frontend!): You need to have one roundtrip to the kernel to have `Needs` update the `$ContextPath`, c.f. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664091/package-import-problem-in-mathematica . And I think knowing what exactly an identifier denotes is crucial in any programming language.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think you both are right but due to the lack of a proper place it is good to have it here. Maybe we could think about another guidelike topic: "Fundamentals that are spread too thinly across documentation", it would fit there best, don't you think?

Comment: I agree with @Michael and @Kuba: currently this post is intended for experienced users who wish to write a package. The ``(Needs["Apackage`"]; PackageFunction[...];)`` case should be included as a point into one of the multi-point answers here (I think [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/280) perfectly fits). Probably we should move this answer to a new thread and include in the OP here a link to that thread with wordings like "This thread is intended primarily to those who learn the basics of the WL. For discussion on subtle/professional topics see *that* thread".

Comment: @MichaelE2 and mastexilo, I tied to polish this topic to make it a generic one about parsing, suggestions appreciated. [119187](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119187/5478)

Answer (score 3):

### `Association` has `HoldAllComplete` attribute

`Association` is not just another head denoting a special kind of list of rules or a certain kind of *object*. It has some properties that make querying it more efficient, but also cause it to behave differently from a List. You should be aware of this if you intend to use `Associations` as a data structure for object oriented programming.

Let me illustrate. Say we want to have a single expression representing a person with the attribute age. We might use a custom head, list or association to store a rule assigning "age" to something. A list and custom head `person` will support *template objects* which have some parameters undefined at the time of their definition. But a head with `HoldAll` such as `hperson` and `Association` will not fill in the blanks once you define them.

```
ClearAll[p1, p2, p3, x, getAgeSquared, hperson];

(*make hperson behave more like Assocation*)
SetAttributes[hperson, HoldAll];

p1 = person["age" -> x]
p2 = List["age" -> x]
p3 = Association["age" -> x]
p4 = hperson["age" -> x]

getAgeSquared@_["age" -> x_Real] := x^2;
(*these stay unevaluated*)
getAgeSquared@p1
getAgeSquared@p2
getAgeSquared@p3
getAgeSquared@p4

x = 3.;

(*note that x is not inserted into structures with HoldAll*)
p1
p2
p3
p4

(*consequently, you cannot do the following successfully with \
Assocation and hperson*)
getAgeSquared@p1
getAgeSquared@p2
getAgeSquared@p3
getAgeSquared@p4
```

The output is

```
person[age->x]
{age->x}
<|age->x|>
hperson[age->x]

getAgeSquared[person[age->x]]
getAgeSquared[{age->x}]
getAgeSquared[<|age->x|>]
getAgeSquared[hperson[age->x]]

person[age->3.]
{age->3.}
<|age->x|>
hperson[age->x]

9.
9.
getAgeSquared[<|age->x|>]
getAgeSquared[hperson[age->x]]
```

#### Example confusion

[Using Associations and Pattern matching in numerical functions possibly broken](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119585/using-associations-and-pattern-matching-in-numerical-functions-possibly-broken#119607)

Comment: I must note that this answer is written in a clumsy way and even to me it is almost impossible to follow your thought (despite the fact that I know in principle what you want to say). I would recommend to rewrite it from the scratch or delete.